# \AtBeginChapter?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, hooks

Are there any hooks that work like `\AtBeginDocument` for chapters, sections, etc.? Something like `\AtBeginChapter`? I would like to have the following code:

```
\AtBeginChapter{%
   \setcounter{mycounter}{2}%
   . . . 
}
```

Yes—I know that I can create my counter so as reset itself whenever a new chapter starts, with

```
\newcounter{mycounter}[chapter]
```

but I would like to have more control as to what happens when a new chapter, section, etc. starts.

Comment: perhaps the `apptocmd` from the `etoolbox`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can redefine `\chapter` to perform the specified tasks before calling the original `\chapter` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \setcounter{mycounter}{2}% Insert "your content" here
  \oldchapter%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\themycounter
\end{document}
```

This works because the `\chapter` macro doesn't gobble its arguments right away (avoiding the choice of using `\LetLtxMacro` from [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro), although it wouldn't hurt). It conditions on a `*` *first*, allowing one to interject your requirements first. Note that the original `\chapter` issues a page break before setting the title (if "your content" should be influenced by this).

The above should hold for the regular `\chapter`-defining document classes as well (`report` and `book`).

Sections are a little easier, since they are provided with a "hook" in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir): `\setsechook{<stuff>}` would execute `<stuff>` before `\section`. It also provides `\setsubsechook` for `\subsection`s and `\setsubsubsechook` for `\subsubsection`s.

Comment: Don't you need `\LetLtxMacro` to take care of all optional parameters?

Comment: How about `chapter[header-title][toc-title]{title}`?

Comment: @NVaughan: See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764) regarding your choices for using `\LetLtxMacro`. `\chapter` in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) technically does not take any arguments, so it's safe to use only `\let`.

Comment: @NVaughan: I'm not sure I understand your second comment. `\chapter` does not gobble the arguments (2 option + 1 mandatory). That is done by a different set of macros: `\@m@mchapter` (that captures the first `[header-title]` optional argument) and `\@chapter` (that captures the second `[toc-title]` optional argument, as well as the mandatory `{title}` argument).