# When to use \LetLtxMacro?

Tags: macros

Frequently I see users redefine macros using (for example)

```
\let\oldmacro\macro% Store \macro in \oldmacro
\renewcommand{\macro}{%
  % ...redefined \macro
  \oldmacro%
}
```

and other times they use

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\LetLtxMacro{\oldmacro}{\macro}% Store \macro in \oldmacro
\renewcommand{\macro}{%
   % ...redefined \macro
  \oldmacro%
}
```

Why would one use `\LetLtxMacro` when `\let` works just as well? Or, more specifically, when would one use `\LetLtxMacro` and/or why?

Comment: See [“Closed” (square) root symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/closed-square-root-symbol).  In particular, see @egreg's comment.

Comment: @A.Ellett The "x mins/hours ago" text at the end of each comment is a link that leads directly to the comment. At the end of each answer there is a light grey  list of functions "share edit flag". The "share" is a link to the corresponding answer as well.

Comment: This is explained clearly in the package documentation.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Only partially, if you read through egreg's answer. There is no mention of it not supporting [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) definitions, nor does it contain the detail provided by his answer.

Comment: See also [macros - Can I redefine a command to contain itself? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

## New answer

A LaTeX kernel later than June 2020 will provide the better

```
\NewCommandCopy
```

but also `\RenewCommandCopy` and `\DeclareCommandCopy`. The first one does the same work as `\LetLtxMacro` as described in the “original answer”, but can also be employed with commands defined via `\NewDocumentCommand` (or siblings).

Differently from `\LetLtxMacro`, it will raise an error if the alias we want is already defined. In this case one can use `\RenewCommandCopy` (that raises an error if the alias is *not* defined) or `\DeclareCommandCopy` (no check is performed). Be careful when using these two forms.

Do prefer `\NewCommandCopy` over `\let`, unless you precisely know that `\let` is OK.

---

## Original answer

There are two main cases when `\LetLtxMacro` should be used (and it doesn't harm if used in other cases).

### Case 1

The command to get a copy of has been defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{-#1-}
```

(with *any* number of arguments, even zero). There are other commands defined in different ways, but at the end come up as being in this same case.

What happens here is that LaTeX defines *two* commands, in a way similar to this

```
\def\foo{\protect\foo•}
\newcommand\foo•[1]{-#1-}
```

where by `•` I mean a ***space*** in the name of the second command. How this trick is achieved is unimportant. We can realize if a command is of this kind by asking `texdef`: with the command line

```
> texdef -t latex texttt
```

we get

```
\texttt:
macro:->\protect \texttt  

\texttt :
\long macro:#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\ttfamily #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}\ttfamily \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi
```

This shows precisely what's happening: `texdef` prints first the meaning of `\texttt`, which is `\protect\texttt•` (the space here is invisibile), but then know about the nature of this command and so prints also the meaning of `\texttt•` and this is shown by the space before the colon.

What would be the problem in doing

```
\let\oldfoo\foo
\renewcommand\foo[1]{!\oldfoo{#1}!}
```

for changing the working of `\foo`? Let's see what happens (I'll continue to use `•` for denoting the space in the name of a macro).

```
\foo{BAR}
!\oldfoo{BAR}!
!\protect\foo•{BAR}!
!-BAR-!
```

which seems pretty good: the renewed macro does what we want. But wait! We use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to be sure that `\foo` in moving arguments is treated correctly. So let's see what happens when `\foo{BAR}` is used in a moving argument, such as a section title; the annotation in the `.toc` file will contain

```
!\foo  {BAR}!
```

which in the end will result in printing `!!-BAR-!!`, which is *not* what we want. Why? Because the writing process expands unprotected macros. So LaTeX does

```
\foo{BAR}
!\oldfoo{BAR}!
!\protect\foo•{BAR}!
!\foo• {BAR}!
```

Since `\foo•` was preceded by `\protect`, the last line is what's written. But when the `.toc` file is read in, TeX only sees a space after `\foo`, because it inputs a text file, so it will dutily expand `\foo`.

If one uses

```
\LetLtxMacro{\oldfoo}{\foo}
```

LaTeX will essentially do

```
\def\oldfoo{\protect\oldfoo•}
\let\oldfoo•\foo•
```

so that the problem above will not appear any more.

### Case 2

If the command we want to save the meaning of has been defined with `\newcommand` to have an optional argument, then there are risks like in the previous case; they are explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4427). The situation is of the form

```
\newcommand{\xyz}[2][!]{#1-#2}
```

and, for instance, `\smash` (as redefined by `amsmath`) falls in this case. With

```
texdef -t latex -p amsmath smash
```

we'd get

```
\smash:
macro:->\@protected@testopt \smash \\smash {tb}
```

and this is a clear sign that `\LetLtxMacro` should be used.

### Other cases

If the command to save has been defined with `\newrobustcmd` from the `etoolbox` package, then `\LetLtxMacro` should be used in order to safely copy its meaning.

### *Warning*

Don't try `\LetLtxMacro` with commands defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` (or similar commands) from `xparse`. The `letltxmacro` package doesn't support them.

Comment: Say I don't want to take risks!. Can I use `\LetLtxMacro` for *all* instances (everywhere)? Will it hurt if done so? (I read your first line but want confirmation)

Comment: @HarishKumar If the macro is not risky, then `\LetLtxMacro` does nothing different from `\let`.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I assume, I’m not the only one, who did not know this.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning `\NewCommandCopy` and friends.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Certainly so!