# Get current error mode

Tags: tex-core

How can one get the current error mode. e.g., is batchmode, scrollmode, etc set? I would like to save and restore these modes in lua or be able to have a macro save the current state that can be called later to restore it.

e.g., `\savemode` and `\restoremode`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91592/where-to-find-official-and-extended-documentation-for-tex-latexs-commandlin where you also find how to do the thing you want.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

[etex](/questions/tagged/etex) added `\interactionmode`.

> When used as number, `\interactionmode` returns one of the values 0 (batchmode), 1 (nonstopmode), 2 (scrollmode), or 3 (errorstopmode). Assigning one of these values to `\interactionmode` changes the current interaction mode accordingly; such assignments are always global.

Node that last part: "*such assignments are always global*".