# Is it possible to detect, inside a package, whether `\errorstopmode` is in effect?

Tags: interaction

The title says it all: can I test, inside a package or a macro, whether `\errorstopmode` is in effect?

Comment: Apparently e-TeX has `\interactionmode` to see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91592/35864

Comment: Aha: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355759/35864