# Optional argument to \item to appear in brackets after the counter

Tags: numbering, enumerate, enumitem, description

Usually, when you have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Mary
\item[had] a little 
\item lamb
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It will format as

```
  1. Mary
had a little
  2. lamb
```

I would want it to format as

```
  1. Mary
  2 (had). a little
  3. lamb
```

In other words, I would like the optional argument that can be passed to an `\item` not to replace the usual label, but I want it to appear additionally. In particular, the counter should still be stepped.

This might seem like a subtlety, but note that the argument should appear before the period and after the counter. In fact, this is just a minimal example - I would like to have greater flexibility in placing the optional argument within the label.

Is there a way to do this with the `enumitem` package?

Comment: A simple solution would be `\item (had) a little`, but perhaps that is not an option.

Comment: What about references? How should item 2 be referenced? With 2 or with 2(had)?

Comment: Just with **2**, as in, with the usual counter value.

Comment: It would be interesting to know _why_ you don't just do it as Peter Grill suggests. Could you please add that to the question? Thanks!

Comment: It's basically in the comment to Peters answer, but I put it in the original question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\labeltext{}
\newcommand\specialitem[1][]{%
 {\renewcommand\labeltext{ (#1)}\item\leavevmode}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\noexpand\labeltext.]
\item Mary
\specialitem[had] a little 
\item lamb
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

1. I'm using a special command but it should also be possible to patch `\item` but then you would loose the standard behaviour.
2. The correct alignment of the label is left as an exercise ;-).

Comment: That's clever! Also, it does exactly what I want. Also, exercise solved. Thanks a bunch! =)

Comment: I do not fully understand, what you do, so it might be superfluous, but: Jesko writes in a comment to egreg above, that for the references he wants only the counters without the added text. In enumitem for such cases exists an option `ref`, here I would suggest `ref=\arabic*.`.

Comment: No no, don't worry, this is precisely what I wanted. I am using cleveref anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can define you own custom environment in which you redefine `\item` macro:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you wish to redefine a macro that has optional parameters, you have to use `\LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) . A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question at [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro).
- I have used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) for string comparison as I prefer its syntax, but this can be done without that pacakge if required.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldItem}{\item}
\newenvironment{MyEnumerate}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\OldItem \IfStrEq{##1}{}{}{(##1)}}%
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnumerate}
    \item Mary
    \item[had] a little 
    \item lamb
\end{MyEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This might seem like a subtlety, but I would want the argument to appear *before* the period and *after* the counter. More precisely, I would like to have greater flexibility in placing the optional argument within the label.