# Repeat an enumerate list in different order - an enumitem question

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want an enumerate list be repeated in a different order (for example, a list of two statements and later a list of two proofs: first the second statement proof and then the first statement proof). I expected that the following code would do this, but in some reason it just produces a regular list with "0" strings.

Please help to find and correct my error.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*$^\circ$.,ref=\arabic*$^\circ$}

\newlist{enumeratex}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[enumeratex]%
{label=\arabic*$^\circ$.,%
before={\let\olditem=\item\renewcommand\item[1][]{\olditem[#1.]}},%
after={\let\item=\olditem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{a} a
  \item \label{b} b
\end{enumerate}

into

\begin{enumeratex}
  \item[\ref{b}] proof of b
  \item[\ref{a}] proof of a
\end{enumeratex}


\end{document}
```

The desired output is:

[image: Two lists]

Optionally, I want the second list labels to be hyperlinks to first list labels.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the desired output is, but I think you need to define a macro for each of the cases. `\ref` is used to provide a reference (clickable if `hyperref` is used) -- it does NOT duplicate the content (assuming that is what you are after).

Comment: @PeterGrill The first list is correct in the output. The second list should be like the first list, but with second item before the first (1 and 2 reversed).

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't need to duplicate the content, just to duplicate a list labels in possibly different order

Comment: Instead of describing it, can you post an image of exactly what the desired output should be.

Comment: @PeterGrill I've added an image with desired output to the question

Comment: I found one error: It should be `\olditem[#1.]` rather than `\olditem{#1.}`, but this way it anyway does not work as expected

Comment: I've corrected in the question the error which I mentioned in the previous comment, but LaTeX produces a wrong result anyway. Please help to find the remaining errors in my code

Comment: Please update the title to some that is specific to your question so that it useful to a wider audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of [Optional argument to \item to appear in brackets after the counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101410/optional-argument-to-item-to-appear-in-brackets-after-the-counter) for your case:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you wish to redefine a macro that has optional parameters, you have to use `\LetLtxMacro` from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) . A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question at [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*$^\circ$.,ref=\arabic*$^\circ$}

\LetLtxMacro{\OldItem}{\item}

\newcommand*{\LabelText}{}%
\newcommand*{\MyItem}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\LabelText}{#1}\OldItem\leavevmode%
}%

\newlist{enumeratex}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[enumeratex]%
{label=\noexpand\LabelText.,%
before={\let\item\MyItem},%
after={\let\item\OldItem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{a} a
  \item \label{b} b
\end{enumerate}

into

\begin{enumeratex}
  \item[\ref{b}] proof of b
  \item[\ref{a}] proof of a
\end{enumeratex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but (out of pure curiosity) why my code did not work?

Comment: @porton:  Part of it has to with the `\LetLtxMacro` as per the link in the question, but not sure I can explain it fully. I only know how to get things to work by referencing previous solutions.   My rep is very misleading. :-)