# How to redefine a command properly to avoid recursive call to itself?

Tags: macros

I'm trying to renew a command in terms of its old definition... something similar to this:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\vec{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

But this seems to send the interpreter in an infinite loop. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 29):

You can use the `\let` command to help you as follows

```
\let\oldvec\vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\oldvec{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldvec\vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\oldvec{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\vec{x}+\vec{y}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Hmm, it seems like this "pollutes" the following code with the definition of `oldvec`. Is there any way to avoid that (and also not rely on `oldvec` being undefined in the beginning)?

Comment: @Mehrdad, the _pollution_ of `oldvec` _should_ not be noticeable. And often one might be forced to use the other definition (take for example `\varphi` and `\phi` which I often change the order of by `\let\ophi\phi\let\ovarphi\varphi\let\phi\ovarphi\let\varphi\ophi`, etc. It doesn't really matter in terms of efficiency, if thats what you are worried about?

Comment: Nah it's not efficiency, it's just that, being a programmer, it feels like bad practice to me, so if there's a way to make it foolproof I'd rather do that. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: cmhughes' uses the idiomatic technique here.  From the point of view of debugging, it is easier to see what is happening if one macro is defined in terms of another than to partially expand out the old macro (which should be possible using `\expandafter`).

Comment: @CharlesStewart: I see, thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 10):

You can avoid defining an "intermediate" command in some cases; consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\show\foo

\begingroup\def\temp{\renewcommand\foo[1]}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\foo{\textbf{#1}}}
\show\foo
\show\temp
```

The log file will show

```
> \foo=\long macro:
#1->\mbox {#1}.
l.3 \show\foo

? 
> \foo=\long macro:
#1->\mbox {\textbf {#1}}.
l.8 \show\foo

? 
> \temp=undefined.
l.9 \show\temp
```

so you can see that `\foo` has been redefined as the original `\foo`, but with the argument printed boldface, whereas `\temp` is still undefined. So we actually use an intermediate command, but its definition is forgotten as soon as the redefinition is performed.

This works with `\vec`; however `\vec` is *not* a macro with argument, as `\show\vec` will show:

```
> \vec=macro:
->\mathaccent "017E\relax .
```

where `\mathaccent` is a TeX primitive. Yes, this works:

```
\begingroup\def\temp{\renewcommand\vec[1]}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\temp\expandafter{\vec{\textbf{#1}}}
```

I leave to your judgement as a programmer if this is clearer than

```
\let\LaTeXvec\vec
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\LaTeXvec{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

TeX is different from other programming languages, because it works mainly by *macro expansion* and a macro can have just one definition at a given time.

However, one has to take *much* care not only to check whether `\LaTeXvec` is defined (using a complicated prefix rather than `old` is usually safe). There are ***big*** problems if the command we want to save is not defined simply with `\newcommand` (or `\def`). See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro) for some of them. In those cases the `\expandafter` path shown above will definitely not work.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In the first case, every attempt of that kind will fail miserably. This way works in various cases, but certainly is much more difficult if something has to be put *before* the original command. Thus the `\let` or, better, `\LetLtxMacro` road is surely preferable.