# Avoid recursion in \renewenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to redefine an environment in order to add a command after the `\begin` without having to add this command in manually everywhere.

For example, I'd like to replace every instance of `\begin{figure}` with `\begin{figure}\foo` where `\foo` is a function I've defined earlier:

```
\newcommand{foo}{This is foobar}
```

If I simply do:

```
\renewenvironment{figure}{\begin{figure}\foo}{\end{figure}}
```

then this creates a recursive definition of the `figure` environment. 
[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101694/31839) suggests using an intermediate command to get past the recursion problem when using `\renewcommand`.

But how can I get past the recursion problem when using `\renewenvironment`?

Comment: It works basically the same...

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments.  You need to save original definitions, and redefine the environment in terms of the saved components.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, this answer will be used to solve my problem. The fact I'm currently struggling to work out *exactly* how to apply it to my problem suggests it's not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patching existing environments or commands is almost a black art. One has to know in detail how the environment or command works.

Even saving a copy of `\figure` the newly defined environment will not work like the original one, particularly with respect to optional arguments.

The best place where placing code to be executed at every `figure` is in `\@floatboxreset`.

However, since you want to do it only for `figure`, there's something more to do.

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\londonrob@floatcode{\@captype}}
\newcommand\londonrob@floatcode[1]{\@nameuse{londonrob@#1code}}
\newcommand\londonrob@figurecode{WHATEVER}
% similarly for \londonrob@tablecode if needed
\makeatother
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\londonrob@floatcode{\@captype}}
\newcommand\londonrob@floatcode[1]{\@nameuse{londonrob@#1code}}
\newcommand\londonrob@figurecode{WHATEVER}
% similarly for \londonrob@tablecode if needed
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]

Something else

\caption{A caption}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Of course, in place of `WHATEVER` you'll add the code you want to be executed.

[image]

Comment: Ouch. I never expected to have to get in this deep. There's a lot to learn in this example. Could you mention what the exact pitfalls of the `\let\temp\figure`-approach are? It looks to me as if redefining `figure` in this way works ok.

Comment: @LondonRob `\figure` expands to `\@float{figure}` and this in turn looks for the optional argument in quite an indirect fashion. If you say `\let\oldfigure\figure` and then `\renewcommand{\figure}{\oldfigure\foo}` the optional argument will never be found.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to add something to the `figure` environment, you can try this:

```
\def\foo{This is foobar}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\addto\figure{\foo}
```

Comment: Sorry, no, it can't work; `\figure` expands to `\@float{figure}` and `\@float` does a check for the optional argument.

Comment: It works. That is all.

Comment: Really? Try `\begin{figure}[htp]`.

Comment: OP needs to substitute `\begin{figure}\foo` not `\begin{figure}[htp]\foo`.

Comment: That's exactly the point: such a substitution would be completely useless. Question: “Can I jump off the tour Eiffel?” Your answer: “Yes, just jump”. My answer: “Get a parachute before jumping.”.

Comment: The parachute is very dangerous when you are jumping off the Eiffel. There is no time to open it.