# Using a command to append data to another one

Tags: macros

I've just wanted to add some elements to an existing command/variable without success. There are many examples for different ways on how to achieve that goal, but none of them seem to work for me.

In the following minimal working example, I've tried to copy the solution from there https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101694/109350

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWS}
\author{r2p2}
\date{July 2016}

\newcommand{\features}[0]{}
\newcommand{\feature}[1] {
        \let\oldfeatures\features
        \renewcommand{\features}[0]{\oldfeatures, #1}
    }

\feature{one}
\feature{two}
\feature{three}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\features

\end{document}
```

But I get

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\oldfeatures ->\oldfeatures 
                            , two
```

as error message, which should not happen, seince oldfeatures is just an old copy of features does not contain features itself. What do I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want to obtain is not clear to me. Should it be \feature{one] -> `one`, \feature{two} -> `one, two` and  \feature{three} -> `one, two, three`?

Comment: Thanks. My idea is to list a bunch of features and bugfixes and let them be automatically grouped together. In the final version, this comma separated list will become itemized and I don't want to write `\begin{itemize} \item myspecialfeature ... \end{itemize}` everytime. Instead, I want to automate the list creation. Which makes it overall easier to read if you just see a list of `\feature {this}`. (Hope that makes sense.)

Comment: @r2p2: If you are after simpler list display, take a look on my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317680/new-command-for-automatic-enumerate-generation/317682#317682

Comment: So many answers.. thats amazingly overwhelming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\newcommand*\features{}
\newcommand*\feature[1]
  {\ifx\features\empty
     \def\features{#1}%
   \else
     \expandafter\def\expandafter\features\expandafter{\features, #1}%
   \fi}
```

In any case, LaTeX2e provides `\g@addto@macro` to deal with a general case.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\features{}
\newcommand*\feature[1]
  {\ifx\features\empty
     \def\features{#1}%
   \else
     \g@addto@macro\features{, #1}%
   \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Oh, now I see. Besides the renewcommand, I've also tried the `\g@addto@macro` but wrong: `\g@addto@macro\features{\features, #1}`.

Comment: For now, I ended up with this version. Don't know if it is the best one but I can understand it and that is most important for me for now. I also got the \ifx syntax for free, which I needed to solve another problem. So thank you for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't define a macro in terms of itself. There are several ways to do what you want, simple or complicated.

Here's the possibly simplest

```
\makeatletter
\let\features\@gobble
\makeatother
\newcommand{\feature}[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\features\expandafter{\features,#1}%
}
```

After

```
\feature{one}
\feature{two}
\feature{three}
```

the expansion of `\features` will be

```
> \features=macro:
->one,two,three.
```

(you see there's no comma at the beginning).

However, this would behave badly if you try to use `\features` when nothing has been added yet. With `etoolbox` you can do better:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\features}{}
\newcommand{\feature}[1]{%
  \ifdefempty{\features}
    {\appto\features{#1}}
    {\appto\features{,#1}}%
}
```

Comment: (+1) Didn't you forget to type a final `\features` in  the definition of `\feature` with `etoolbox`? Also, I'd write `\features{, #1}}%` with a space after the comma.

Comment: @Bernard The space is at discretion of the OP, it depends on how the macro should be used. I don't understand where `\features` should be added: I don't think that printing the value each time `\feature` is called is wanted.

Comment: I tried your code, as I found it quite elegant, but it didn't print whatever. Adding `\features`  just before the last closing bracket did print successfully.

Comment: @Bernard Actually it is not meant to print anything. The macro `\features` will be used somewhere.

Comment: OK! I misunderstood the aim of the command. I thought it was supposed to add an item to a list and print the completed list. Sorry for having disturbed you. I'll delete my comments in a moment.