# Use \LetLtxMacro with a \Macro* (starred variant)

Tags: macros, starred-version

If I use:

```
\LetLtxMacro{\MacroToUse}{\FormatText}
```

then using `\MacroToUse` invokes `\FormatText` exactly as desired.  But, how do use this construct to invoke `\FormatText*`?

The MWE below yields:

[image]

but the desired output is the two lines being identical.

### References:

- [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\newcommand*{\FormatColor}{}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatText}{s m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \def\FormatColor{red}%
    }{%
        \def\FormatColor{blue}%
    }%
    \textcolor{\FormatColor}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatText{one}
\FormatText*{two}

\newcommand{\MacroToUse}{}%

\LetLtxMacro{\MacroToUse}{\FormatText}%
\MacroToUse{one}
\LetLtxMacro{\MacroToUse}{\FormatText*}%
\MacroToUse{two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your questions can be used as `model` for all. very nice

Comment: `\LetLtxMacro` and, in general, all patching commands should not be used with macros defined with `xparse` facilities. In this case `\def\MacroToUse{\FormatText*}` is more than sufficient. There's no reason for using `\LetLtxMacro` here.

Comment: So you don't want to use `\MacroToUse*`?

Comment: @Werner: Have a complex piece of code that I would prefer to not duplicate, or repackage in another macro.  it currently calls the starred variant, so would be really nice if I could select to use the starred or no starred variant, and then not have to think about it later in the code.

Comment: You can create an auxiliary macro `\newcommand*{\FormatTextStar}{\FormatText*}` for which `\LetLtxMacro{\MacroToUse}{\FormatTextStar}` would work...

Comment: @Werner: Yep that too would work, but as egreg pointed out I was totally on the wrong track to be using `\LetLtxMacro` (or even `\let`) as I am _not_ changing the behavior of the macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a place where `\LetLtxMacro` should *not* be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\newcommand*{\FormatColor}{}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatText}{s m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \def\FormatColor{red}%
    }{%
        \def\FormatColor{blue}%
    }%
    \textcolor{\FormatColor}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\FormatText{one}
\FormatText*{two}

\newcommand{\MacroToUse}{\FormatText}
\MacroToUse{one}

\renewcommand{\MacroToUse}{\FormatText*}
\MacroToUse{two}
\end{document}
```

Using `\let` or its more powerful sibling `\LetLtxMacro` is basically for when you want to save the meaning of a macro in order to redefine it or, in general, when the other macro can change its meaning afterwards and you want to have its original meaning available, perhaps to restore it.

Here you never modify `\FormatText`, so there's no need to save its meaning.

If you're worrying about the arguments, don't. When TeX sees

```
\MacroToUse{two}
```

in the code above, it will look up the current meaning of `\MacroToUse` and, since it ia a macro, replace it with the replacement text. So at this stage it will be presented with

```
\FormatText*{two}
```

which is just what's needed.

---

In any case, you *can't* use

```
\LetLtxMacro{\foo}{\baz*}
```

assuming that `\baz` has a *-variant. The second argument to `\LetLtxMacro` should be a *single* token, and `\baz*` is two tokens. The `*` doesn't make part of the macro's name.