# Problem with \renewcommand

Tags: macros, graphics, footnotes

I am trying to use `\renewcommand` to change the size of footnotes throughout the main text. I do this by changing `\footenotesize` to a different command, `\scriptsize`. Later on, I would like the command `\footnotesize` to return to its original use. But, using `\renewcommand` again to do this causes my .tex file to stop compiling, typically on the first `\includegraphics` command. Even without the `\includegraphics` command, the .tex file will not compile. I don't understand what's going on, but if I remove the second `\renewcommand`, the document compiles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Graphics package to include figures (need graphicx.sty)

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}

Here is some text. And Here is some text with a footnote.\footnote{Here is the footnote text.}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Probability of Leaving within One Year: 1999-2002}
        \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=4in]{combined-one-3060-vertical.eps}
   \end{center}
\label{fig:leave1-baseline}
{\footnotesize
Notes:  The top panel plots the average leave probability for one-year age bins for the 2002 sample, while the bottom panel separately plots these probabilities for the 2002 and 1999-2001 samples.
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are using the same command as new and as old command in

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize}
```

The right way to do it, is to first save the meaning of `\footnotesize`

```
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
```

and when you want to restore its meaning, use

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\oldfootnotesize}
```

So, modifying your MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   % Graphics package to include figures (need graphicx.sty)

\begin{document}

\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}

Here is some text. And Here is some text with a footnote.\footnote{Here is the footnote text.}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\oldfootnotesize}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Probability of Leaving within One Year: 1999-2002}
        \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=4in]{combined-one-3060-vertical.eps}
   \end{center}
\label{fig:leave1-baseline}
{\footnotesize
Notes:  The top panel plots the average leave probability for one-year age bins for the 2002 sample, while the bottom panel separately plots these probabilities for the 2002 and 1999-2001 samples.
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

works.

Answer (score 9):

You are creating a circular reference which exhausts TeX's capacity when you do something like

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize}
```

The typical way to deal with temporary changes in TeX is to use a *localization technique* or *scoping*:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
% do stuff
\endgroup
```

This will restore the original meaning of `\footnotesize` after `\endgroup`. Alternatively, you would use an intermediate variable in the following way:

```
\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
% do stuff
\let\footnotesize\oldfootnotesize
```

The use of `\let<csname1><csname2>` makes an immediate copy of `<csname2>` into `<csname1>` at the time of calling. Depending on the type of control sequences, [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) provides a secure alternative. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)

While the above hopefully answers the question, doing this is not suggested nor encouraged. In fact, using

```
\footnote{\scriptsize Here is the footnote text.}
```

is probably just as good without the complication(s).

Comment: Why is this not encouraged?

Comment: @stanford202: You're temporarily influencing a typographical element in the document, which affects [consistency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). Also, while you're interested in changing the size of a `\footnote`'s text, other document elements contained within your redefinition might use `\footnotesize` that you're not aware of. Certainly your example is very small and my discussion provides a general approach to this.

Comment: @stanford202 I think "not encouraged" is just Werner being polite: "don't do this!" might be a more accurate description:-) `\footnotesize` is one of a graded series of sizes that can be (and is) used for all kinds of purposes other than footnotes. Better to simply redefine `\footnotetext` to use `\scriptsize` rather than `\footnotesize`

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this in a different way, so `\renewcommand` can work without redefining kernel commands such as `\footnotesize` that are rather delicate to deal with.

The choice of the font used in the footnote text is made by `\@footnotetext`, so our first job is to make an indirect call instead of a direct one:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % this goes among the other instructions of the same type

% the following code should be in the preamble
\makeatletter % we must add to commands with an @ in their name
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\footnotesize}
  {\footnotefontsize}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\footnotesize}
\makeatother
```

With this code we have made no real change to the font size; but now you're free to say

```
\renewcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\scriptsize}
```

or even (hopefully not)

```
\renewcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\Large}
```

or, probably

```
\renewcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\footnotesize}
```

### Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % this goes among the other instructions of the same type

% the following code should be in the preamble
\makeatletter % we must add to commands with an @ in their name
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\footnotesize}
  {\footnotefontsize}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a\footnote{First}

\renewcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\Large}

b\footnote{Second}

\renewcommand{\footnotefontsize}{\footnotesize}

c\footnote{Third}
\end{document}
```

[image]