# white space before \citep Macro

Tags: citing

I am working on big book and need to ensure that all citations have a white space before them. I tried

```
 \let\citep ~\citep
```

But that does not seem the right thing to do. Could you please help.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

there are two things wrong with your attempt.

`\let` equates the specified command to the next single command.  even though it may not
look like one, `~` is in fact a command (for an unbreakable space).  so you have just
defined `\citep` to be an unbreakable space.

even if you had used the more appropriate approach -- `\renewcommand{\citep}{~\citep}` --
you would have run into the problem that, without "freezing" the original meaning of
`\citep`, this would result in an unending loop.

a reliable approach is to define an entirely new command:

```
\newcommand{\mycitep}{~\citep}
```

here the original meaning of `\citep` is never compromised, and if you change your
mind, it's easy to change the definition.  this also allows you to use the original
`\citep` if it is needed, for example, to start a sentence, where a preceding space
would be inappropriate.

Comment: Isn't the space adding default if you load the `cite` package with the `space` option (really annoying if you want to use it in context where the sapce is not wanted).

Comment: @daleif -- that's why i suggested a new name.  admittedly, i wasn't thinking of using a package.

Comment: not easy when it is a tempalte providsed by a publisher.

Comment: @daleif -- good point.  that's why (at ams) we do try to predict how macros might be "misused" before releasing them for general use.  the payback is worth the extra effort up front.  (and of course it's never possible to foresee everything.)

Answer (score 3):

As barbara explained, `\let` is not the right command to use. However, also the proposed solution is not very good, in my opinion.

Since `\citep` is provided by `natbib`, I'll assume it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro{\ORIcitep}{\citep}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citep}{\leavevmode\unskip~\ORIcitep}
```

In this way, `\citep` is defined to do the same as the original command, after removing a possible space before it and adding a tie instead. Without `\unskip`, an input like

```
word~\citep{key}
```

would result in *two* spaces.

Of course it doesn't make sense to use `\citep` at the start of a paragraph. So my advice is *not* to use such a redefinition, but to ensure `~` is typed before `\citep` when necessary.

See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro) for more information about `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: unfortunately, if the redefined `\citep` starts a paragraph, there's an unwanted space at the beginning.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I forgot to add `natbib`. Of course the unwanted space in front of the citation is unavoidable at the start of a paragraph, which is why I wouldn't recommend such an approach. A desired space in output should have a corresponding token in input.

Comment: i don't disagree that starting a paragraph with a citation is a bad thing, but that doesn't mean authors won't do it.  (and i did `\usepackage{natbib}` when i tested it.  you had a comment in your original answer that said you "assumed" it, and for once, i was careful enough to read the whole thing.  i see you've edited a warning into the answer now.)