# Redefine \emph to be both bold and italic

Tags: macros, emphasis

I'm trying to redefine the `\emph` command to make text bolded in addition to being italic, but when I use

```
\newcommand{\bfemph}[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\bfemph{#1}}
```

I get an error message. The first command defining `\bfemph` works on its own, but the latter does not.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Do you even need the `bfemph` command?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to redefine \emph so I was playing around with defining a new command that did what I wanted.

Comment: Ok, I'll change my solution to remove `bfemph`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With latest Latex you can just do

```
\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries\itshape}
```

For nested `\emph` you can provide additional declarations to `\DeclareEmphSequence` separated by comma.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it nowadays.

Answer (score 32):

Rather than redefining `\emph` in terms of a copy of itself, it's better redefining it from scratch, using the standard definition as model; the standard definition is surprisingly simple:

```
% latex.ltx, line 3744:
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
```

because it's `\em` that does the hard work. So we can simply do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\let\emph\relax % there's no \RedeclareTextFontCommand
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries\em}

\begin{document}

Here is \emph{emphasized text with something \emph{emphasized} inside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, double emphasis is really too much: italic is sufficiently prominent. The advantage of redefining `\emph` in this way is that you can simply comment out those two lines and return to the default.

Why doesn't your idea work? Because with those definitions, when TeX finds

```
\emph{text}
```

it changes it into

```
\bfemph{text}
```

and this becomes

```
\textbf{\emph{text}}
```

that in turn becomes

```
{<expansion of \textbf>\emph{text}}
```

…

Sorry, infinite loop: `\emph` will restart the machinery.

Answer (score 6):

You can't define a command by itself, which you are basically doing.
The simplest solution would to just use the `textit` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\bfemph}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\bfemph{#1}}

\begin{document}
Text \bfemph{Text2} \emph{Text3}
\end{document}
```

Of course you don't need the `bfemph` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Text \emph{Text3}
\end{document}
```

This solution **doesn't** have the standard behaviour of `emph` to toggle between modes if you use it recursively.

Comment: That sort of works by luck , but `\let\emphold\emph` doesn't save the real definition of `\emph` it just saves the top level (which is `\def\emph{\protect\emph_}` (where `_` is a space) you happened to use `\renewcommand` rather than `\declarerobustcommand` to redefine `\emph` so the internal definition was not over- written. but if you put that in a moving argument like `\section` it will write to the toc as `\textbf{\emph {xxxx}}`

Comment: A crap.. I didn't know that.

Comment: I will just remove the `\let` definition then. Although I always liked that solution :(

Comment: @JuriRobl You should use `\LetLtxMacro\oldemph\emph` (requires  `\usepackage{letltxmacro}`) instead of `\let`. See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/)