# Redefine \emph to typeset the first level in bold and the second level in bold italic

Tags: fonts, emphasis

I would like to redefine `\emph` that odd emphasised levels are bold and even emphasised levels are bold italic (`\emph{bold \emph{bold italic \emph{bold}}}`). How could I redefine `\emph` using `\em` to achieve this?

I tried to edit the solution proposed here [Redefine \emph to be both bold and italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227639/redefine-emph-to-be-both-bold-and-italic)

```
\let\emph\relax % there's no \RedeclareTextFontCommand
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries\em}
```

But here the first level is always bold and italic.

Comment: Just a caution -- `\emph` may be used "under the covers" in some places where you might not expect it, for example in bibliography styles or caption environments.  Be alert.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the next latex (which will be released in a few days) you can do the following

```
\documentclass{report}
\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries,\itshape,\upshape}
\begin{document}

normal \emph{bold \emph{bold italic \emph{bold}}}

\end{document}
```

You can try it out already in a current tex system by using `pdflatex-dev` instead of `pdflatex`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness.