# Change Color of Proof

Tags: color

I'm using the `\begin{proof}` of the `amsthm` package. And I want to change the color of everything in this environment. Currently, I use `{\color{blue} \begin{proof} ... \end{proof}}`. But I need to do this every time. How can I do it more easily, please? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the label, or of all the text in the proof?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepend `\proof` (similar to `\begin{proof}`) with `\color{blue}` using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}% To colour equation numbers in proof

\let\oldproof\proof
\renewcommand{\proof}{\color{blue}\oldproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof. Here is an equation:
\begin{equation} f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \end{equation}
Here is another equation, this time unnumbered
\[ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \]
And the end of the proof.
\end{proof}

Some text between proofs.
\begin{equation} f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \end{equation}

\begin{proof}[abc]
This is a proof. Here is an equation:
\begin{equation} f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \end{equation}
Here is another equation, this time unnumbered
\[ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \]
And the end of the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The grouping provided by `\begin`...`\end` limits the scope of `\color{blue}` to everything inside the `proof` environment (including math content).

I've added [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) above since it redefines the way tags work under [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). In that sense, it automatically colours equation numbers inside the `proof` environment as well. Without it, you may be left with black equation numbers and have to redefine the tag-form yourself.

The `proof` environment takes an optional argument. In such cases it may be *safer* to use `\LetLtxMacro` (from the similarly-named package) instead of a pure `\let`. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)

Comment: Using `\color{blue}` in vertical mode? Hmm. And `\proof` is a command with optional argument, so `\renewcommand\proof` is quite risky (see the doc of `letltxmacro`).

Answer (score 7):

The package `etoolbox` allows you to easily patch everything:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\color{blue}}
```