# Different color inside the proof environment, only when I want

Tags: color, amsmath, environments

There is the `proof` environment in the `amsmath` package. If I want to globally set the text color inside the `proof` environment, I can use the command

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\color{blue}}
```

as illustrated in [Change Color of Proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236391/change-color-of-proof).

However, suppose that I want to change the color inside the proof *only sometimes*. There may be two (or more) options to achieve this.

Option 1: Define two environments `proof` and `blueproof`, where `proof` is the usual environment and `blueproof` is a custom-made environment that is a copy of the `proof` except that the color inside the proof is blue.

Option 2: Put appropriate options inside the proof, for example,

```
\begin{proof}[here my options to change the color]
...
\end{proof}
```

Either option is fine for me. How can I make the proof color blue when necessary?

**Edit**: Sadly, the below answer does not work.

Running the provided code, I instead obtain:

[image]

with error messages that `Undefined control sequence. \begin{Proof}[blue]`, etc.

Comment: `amsmath` doesn't define any proof environment;, but `amsthm` does.  But you haven't said what theorem package you are using, if any.  So this question can't be answered without more information.  Please supply a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest going to a new environment, because the optional argument is already reserved for an alternative header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Proof}{O{}}
 {
  \color_group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { eigenvalue/proof } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:VF \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   {
    \color_select:V \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   }
  \tl_if_empty:VTF \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl
   {
    \proof
   }
   {
    \proof[\l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl]
   }
 }
 {
  \color_group_end:
  \endproof
 }

\keys_define:nn { eigenvalue/proof }
 {
  color .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl,
  name  .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl,
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_select:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Proof}
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[color=blue!70]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem,color=red!60!blue]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also define shorter keys, for instance `blue` to stand for `color=blue!70` (it's best to never use pure colors).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Proof}{O{}}
 {
  \color_group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { eigenvalue/proof } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:VF \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   {
    \color_select:V \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   }
  \tl_if_empty:VTF \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl
   {
    \proof
   }
   {
    \proof[\l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl]
   }
 }
 {
  \color_group_end:
  \endproof
 }

\keys_define:nn { eigenvalue/proof }
 {
  color .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl,
  name  .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl,
  blue .meta:n = { color = blue!70 },
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_select:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Proof}
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[color=blue!70]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[blue]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem,color=red!60!blue]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to color also the tombstone

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Proof}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { eigenvalue/proof } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:VF \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   {
    \cs_set:Npx \qedsymbol
     {
      \color_select:V \exp_not:N \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl \exp_not:o { \qedsymbol }
     }
   }
  \color_group_begin:
  \tl_if_empty:VF \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   {
    \color_select:V \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl
   }
  \tl_if_empty:VTF \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl
   {
    \proof
   }
   {
    \proof[\l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl]
   }
 }
 {
  \color_group_end:
  \endproof
 }

\keys_define:nn { eigenvalue/proof }
 {
  color .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_color_tl,
  name  .tl_set:N = \l__eigenvalue_proof_name_tl,
  blue .meta:n = { color = blue!70 },
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_select:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Proof}
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[color=blue!70]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[blue]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}[name=Proof of the main theorem,color=red!60!blue]
This is a proof.
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but sadly your code does not work on my environment (see my edited post). Is there any requirement for your code to run?

Comment: @eigenvalue Update your TeX system. Please, show also the error messages you get.