# renewcommand \index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

To make sure I've indexed what I should I want to footnote every indexed item in a draft of my document. The MNWE that follows is what I've tried. The renewed `\index` command properly creates an index entry, but doesn't generate the footnote. `\marginpar` instead of `\footnote` fails too. So does `\marginnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{imakeidx}   % needed in the real document
\usepackage{refcount}   % needed in the real document

\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
%\footnote{INDEXING #1}
\marginnote{#1}
\oldindex{#1}
}

\makeindex[intoc] % needs imakeidx

\begin{document}
Here is an entry\index{entry} to index\index{index}.
Check that margin notes work\marginnote{This is a margin note}
Check that footnotes work\footnote{This is a footnote}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Index can be used in places where float constructions like footnote and marginpar cannot be used. You might want to use marginnote (package of the same name). Also try to search ctan, fairly certain there is a package for this

Comment: You will be struck by the thunderbolts of `egreg` because you misused `index` an his package. Please consider, that `\index` has an optional argument here, which is forgotten with `\let` here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer egreg's thunderbolts are to be avoided at all costs. Will update my MNWE,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delay `\renewcommand{\index}` at begin document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}   % needed in the real document
\usepackage{refcount}   % needed in the real document

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\oldindex}{\index}%
  \renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
    \footnote{INDEXING #1}%
    \marginpar{#1}%
    \oldindex{#1}%
  }%
}

\makeindex[intoc] % needs imakeidx

\begin{document}
Here is an entry\index{entry} to index\index{index}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

<sub>The original answer used `\LetLtxMacro` for reasons explained at [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro) but nowadays `\NewCommandCopy` is to be preferred.</sub>

Not that it's really needed here, but it's better practice any time a command has (or appears to have) an optional argument.

If you also want to support the optional argument to `\index`, then you can use `xparse` that makes things easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}   % needed in the real document
\usepackage{refcount}   % needed in the real document

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\oldindex}{\index}%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{om}{%
    \footnote{INDEXING #2}%
    \marginpar{#2}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\oldindex{#2}}{\oldindex[#1]{#2}}%
  }%
}

\makeindex[intoc] % needs imakeidx

\begin{document}
Here is an entry\index{entry} to index\index{index}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

(I used `\marginpar` throughout, because `\marginnote` results in overlapped entries if on the same line).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even have time to update using `\LetLtxMacro1`.

Comment: @EthanBolker Read my profile page: *Pronto prontissimo son come il fulmine: sono il factotum della città.*

Comment: Google translate says "Ready than ready are like lightning : are the factotum of the city".

Comment: @EthanBolker “Readier than ready, I'm like the lightning: I'm the town's Jack-of-all-trades.” From Rossini's “Il barbiere di Siviglia”.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for exactly the same purpose. leaves \index untouched:

\newcommand{\indx}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5laoz.png){\colorbox{yellow}{\footnotesize #1}\index{#1}}%checking

%\newcommand{\indx}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5laoz.png){\index{#1}} %standard \index

```
\item to toggle perspective view \indx{perspective view},
\item store and select camera positions (snapshots). Only the camera and the view angle (zoom) are stored, not the result type.
\item Legend and status bar can be moved freely on the \indx{Legend!move} screen with the left mouse button pressed.
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: first answer, sorry. it is \newcommand{\indx}[1]{\color...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!