# Make indexed words appear bold in body text

Tags: indexing, bold, imakeidx

I would like to have every word that appears in the index to be set in boldface in the main text, sort of the opposite of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158725/how-can-i-make-a-simple-index-in-latex-that-includes-every-bolded-word-throughou) (where everything typed in bold should be indexed).

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Minimal Working Example}

\lipsum[1-3]
minimal\index{minimal}
\lipsum[4-6]
working\index{working}
\lipsum[7-9]
example\index{example}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this by renewing the `\index` macro. That's a little tricky. Here's an answer that shows you how: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267366/renewcommand-index

Answer (score 4):

I think this does what you want. Of course it doesn't boldface a word that appears in the index when that word appears in the text somewhere it's not indexed. That would be much harder ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}\index{#1}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Minimal Working Example}

\lipsum[1-3]
\boldindex{minimal}
\lipsum[4-6]
\boldindex{working}
\lipsum[7-9]
\boldindex{example}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would not work for the case when `imakeidx`'s feature of `\index[someotherindex]{foo}` is used. And what is with `\index{foo!bar}`. This would appear as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer True enough. Making the fancy features work would require more argument parsing somewhere (maybe already done in the `\index` code). That's beyond my pay grade - someone else will have to step up if the OP needs those features.

Comment: Yes parsing is ... weird. There is also the `@` character for sorting and `|` etc. (+1) anyway!

Comment: @EthanBolker Subindices would certainly be appreciated. Also, is there a way to make this work with indices containing `\lstinline` elements from the `listings` package?

Comment: You seem to be asking for more and more features. If you use those features rarely, consider coding them by hand each time. If you want them automated, please edit your question to include an MWE that illustrates all your needs. Perhaps someone will be able to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for your constructive advice. As there were only few instances where I needed this, I did in fact implement it by hand each time.      I didn't know if this would be easy or hard to implement before asking. I just asked in case it was easy.

Answer (score 3):

This is some extension to Ethan Bolker's answer, which takes `imakeidx` into account and prints the last index entry in a `foo!bar!stuff` index list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xstring}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand{\indexbold}[2][]{%
    \StrCount{#2}{!}[\mycount]% Count the ! in the string
    \ifnum\mycount = 0
    \textbf{#2}%
    \else%
    \expandarg\StrBehind[\mycount]{#2}{!}[\myrestindex]%  get the last entry
    \textbf{\myrestindex}%
    \fi%
    \ifblank{#1}{%
      \index{#2}%
    }{%
      \index[#1]{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}


\makeindex
\begin{document}

\indexbold{foo}
\blindtext[5]

\indexbold{foo again}
\blindtext[5]

\indexbold{foo!bar}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course my approach won't work if the `!` is part of the index entry itself

Comment: I had hoped that there was some implementation of this that would allow me to continue typesetting indexed words in a different face. Using your `\indexbold` on something like `\newcommand{\macro}{\texttt{macro}}` throws an error `Use of \\indexbold doesn't match its definition.`.

Comment: @PacificOrion: Now you are editing the question away from your initial version. There was nothing of `\macro{...}` in your post above.

Comment: It's true that I did not initially mention macros. But I don't think this counts as 'editing' my question away from the original. I'm still posing the same question but asking for a more robust solution.

Comment: @PacificOrion: Well, yes and no. What do you mean by using `\indexbold` on \newcommand{` etc.? What do you want to index there?

Comment: I have a macro to typeset 'C++'. It is implemented as `\newcommand{\cpp}{C\texttt{++}}`. I stumbled upon this error when trying to index `\index{\cpp standard library}`.

Comment: @PacificOrion: I'll try

Comment: Thanks but see the comments below Ethan's answer before spending too much time with the problem. Since there weren't that many of them, I avoided these problems by tampering on a case by case basis.

Comment: @PacificOrion: I've added the `\expandarg` in front of `StrBehind`! The `\cpp...` stuff must be expanded before `\StrBehind` can act on it

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error `Use of \\indexbold doesn't match its definition.`.

Comment: @PacificOrion: well, I can compile my example above

Comment: Yes, but I don't see where it uses `\cpp` or a similar macro inside `\indexbold`.

Comment: @PacificOrion: I don't understand