# Styling \Blindtext and \blindtext (aka renewcommand with optional arguments)

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, blindtext

I am using `blindtext` package to draw out how the layout of the document will look like and then swapping the "dummy" parts with real text. Problem is that I would like to give some style to these text blocks to visually differentiate them from already written text.

I used simply:

```
\let\oldbt\blindtext
\renewcommand{\blindtext}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\oldbt{}}}
```

which worked fine until I wanted to add some arguments or use `\Blindtext`, which internally calls `\blindtext` with arguments.

I found several possibilities to handle optional arguments using `\xparse` or `\NewDocumentCommand`, but none of them was enough descriptive. And I still have some blind believe it must be possible to do using standard `\renewcommand`. I also believe that this will be useful for more people so I am asking new question.

What is the correct way of styling `blindtext`, for example adding `gray` color?

Comment: The color is not grouped, it will also color your usual text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful in redefining commands with an optional argument; instead of `\let` one should use `\LetLtxMacro` (see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,letltxmacro,xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for simulating real text

\LetLtxMacro{\blindtextblindtext}{\blindtext}
\LetLtxMacro{\blindtextBlindtext}{\Blindtext}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\blindtext}{O{\value{blindtext}}}{%
  \begingroup\color{gray}\blindtextblindtext[#1]\endgroup
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Blindtext}{O{\value{blindtext}}O{\value{Blindtext}}}{%
  \begingroup\color{gray}\blindtextBlindtext[#1][#2]\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\blindtext[3]

\lipsum[3]

\Blindtext[2][3]

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine. I spend too much time searching in the problem in the `\renewcommand`, and didn't realize there might be problem with the `\let` part.