# Using `\textbf{}` to make also math bold in sentence

Tags: math-mode, bold

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the \textbf{open ball of radius $r$ around $x$} is the set 

\begin{equation}
    B_r(x) := \{y \in M : d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility that the math symbols are also bold by default, i.e. without writing explicitly something like `\mathbf{a + b}`?

Comment: `\boldmath` somewhere before `\textbf`, but it does not look nice having both text and math in bold font, in my point of view. `\boldmath` enables bold math (if the symbol is available in bold font at all) for the rest of the document or until `\unboldmath` undoes it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh really nice! Just made the command `\newcommand{\bld}[1]{\boldmath\textbf{#1}\unboldmath}` for highlighting something and it worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: not relevant to question, but ... please do not leave a blank line before `\begin{equation}`. it messes up the vertical spacing,

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you so much! This was bothering me all the time when I wrote my report.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh dear, that was very enlightening, I've been doing it wrong all the time, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update 2023

With a newer release of LaTeX, there's a much better way to accomplish the task.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\AddToHook{cmd/bfseries/after}{\boldmath}
\AddToHook{cmd/normalfont/after}{\unboldmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Bad typesetting}

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the 
\textbf{open ball of radius $r$ around $x$} is the set 
\begin{equation}
    B_r(x) := \{y \in M : d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}

Let's see: \textbf{M \normalfont \(M\) M}

\section{Good typesetting}

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the 
\emph{open ball of radius~$r$ around~$x$} is the set 
\begin{equation}
    B_r(x) := \{y \in M : d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Older answer, don't use unless you have an old TeX distribution.

You might update the definition of `\bfseries` to also issue `\boldmath`.
However I recommend using `\emph` for emphasis.

Never leave a blank line before an `equation` or other math display environment. Use ties, as I show in the second example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf
  \fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
  \boldmath % <-- added
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Bad typesetting}

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the 
\textbf{open ball of radius $r$ around $x$} is the set 
\begin{equation}
    B_r(x) := \{y \in M : d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}

\section{Good typesetting}

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the 
\emph{open ball of radius~$r$ around~$x$} is the set 
\begin{equation}
    B_r(x) := \{y \in M : d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is it bad using boldface type? Because it's too heavy. Why is it worse to embolden math? Because math symbols have a meaning that also depends on their typographic nature: to a mathematician, a boldface italic ‘r’ is *not* the same as a medium italic ‘r’.

Comment: @Kobi You should have first commented that the answer does no longer work: it did at the time it was written. Anyway, I provided a new answer that works with the current LaTeX. Here the custom is quite different than in SO.

Comment: If it is worse to embolden math is subjective or context-sensitive. If someone may have two different symbols being the same letter in different styles, it is. If not, it isn't. I avoid having such symbols because distinguishing them while reading is difficult and to have the option to typeset maths in different styles. Like I do not read the boldness in normal text, I do not read the boldness in math text.

Comment: That solution (Update 2023) breaks (behaves unintuitively) when the font is switched inside a `\textbf`. The result of `\textbf{\normalfont \(M\) M}` is that the textual M is normal and the mathematical M is bold. I think that this result is undesirable. This problem is encountered in (among others) description lists when I use enumitem and have `\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}` to have the labels in the normal font. The labels are bold by default, so it makes maths bold, and `\normalfont` doesn't unenbolden it. It could be fixed by redefining `\normalfont` to include `\unboldmath`.

Comment: @matj1 Fixed as requested

Answer (score 6):

Update `\textbf` to also execute `\boldmath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\oldtextbf{\boldmath #1}}

\begin{document}
Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For any $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the \textbf{open ball of radius~$r$ around~$x$} is the set 
\begin{equation}
  B_r(x) \vcentcolon= \{y \in M \mid d(y,x) < r\}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

For some this may change the notation, since there could be a different interpretation of *r* and ***r***, for example.

---

A wiser choice for the redefinition of `\textbf`:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldtextbf\textbf% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbf}[1]{\oldtextbf{\boldmath #1}}
```

Comment: Be careful when doing this to robustified commands.

Comment: @egreg: It may be better to declare it robust so as to avoid issues with a possible expansion of `\boldmath`. Or `\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\oldtextbf{\protect\boldmath #1}}`?

Comment: Look at the documentation of `letltxmacro` to know why, or [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/). Doing `\DeclareRobustMacro{\textbf}[1]{\oldtextbf{\boldmath#1}}` leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the `:=`. I think that it might be preferable still to use `\coloneqq` (also from `mathtools`), defined as `\mathrel{\vcentcolon\mkern-1.2mu=}`.