# How to get around \renewcommand?

Tags: macros

Say I've redefined some command

```
\renewcommand{\oldcommand}{\newcommand}
```

If I want to use this new command everywhere in my LaTex document except for once or twice, where I need to make use of the old command, is there a way to use the old command, without getting rid of my \renecommand statement?

This is a hypothetical question, so I don't have a concrete example of a document  where I would need an answer to this, but I am curious.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\let\oldmacro\macro\renewcommand\macro{whatever}` When you need the original meaning, use `\oldmacro`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldLarge\Large
\renewcommand{\Large}{\Huge}
\begin{document}
This is {\Large now huge}

This is {\oldLarge still Large}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

There are some circumstances in which this simple approach won't work, depending on how the command you're redefining was defined initially.  See:

- [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/2693)