# perltex fails when using fourier package macro expression as argument to perl macro

Tags: perl, fourier

After some search for errors, I have defined the following little example to show my issue.

The command `perltex` can nicely translate the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand\simplycopy[1]{
    return $_[0];
}

\begin{document}
    This works: $\mathbb{N}$

    This does not when using fourier: $\simplycopy{\mathbb{N}}$
\end{document}
```

Mind that the use of the fourier package has been commented out. If I want to use fourier, however, by changing two lines to be

```
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
```

I get an error

> ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.1 \math
>            @bb  {N}\endinput ?

Apparently, perltex runs into a problem with some internally used font macro name `\math@bb`.

*Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in perltex or maybe in fourier?*

The automatically generated lgpl-file contains the following data:

```
############################### PERL CODE ################################
sub latex_simplycopy {
return $_[0];
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LATEX RESULT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


############################### PERL CODE ################################
latex_simplycopy ('\\math@bb  {N}');

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LATEX RESULT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\math@bb  {N}
```

so I can see that `perltex` has added an `@` character to the original macro input `\mathbb{N}`, and this may be related to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `fourier` package does

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\math@bb}
```

which sort of works, but not really. See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro\mathbb\math@bb}
\makeatother

\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand\simplycopy[1]{return $_[0];}

\begin{document}

This works: $\mathbb{N}$

This works too: $\simplycopy{\mathbb{N}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]