# Output of PerlTex with current TeXlive on Windows

Tags: perl

I am learning with PerlTeX on Windows in TeXworks. I have simple question, for which I wasnt able to find answer in package PerlTeX documentation:

Is it possible to output PerlTeX compilation into .pdf?

So far I am able to output only into .dvi, which is for me very unsuitable.
If testing is needed, please consider this MWE (actually taken from egregs wonderful answer [perltex fails when using fourier package macro expression as argument to perl macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387891/perltex-fails-when-using-fourier-package-macro-expression-as-argument-to-perl-ma))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro\mathbb\math@bb}
\makeatother

\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand\simplycopy[1]{return $_[0];}

\begin{document}

This works: $\mathbb{N}$

This works too: $\simplycopy{\mathbb{N}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you invoke PerlTeX on Windows; from a Unix terminal, `perltex --latex=pdflatex <filename>` will use `pdflatex` and produce PDF output.

Comment: @egreg Yes! That is correct!
If I use windows command-line, it works.
I am using TeXworks, created a "New Tool" in "Settings" with arguments:
$basename
--latex=pdflatex
In order to reproduce same behaviour.  Did I misstepped somewhere?
EDIT: I may edit the question in order to supplement those informations, if you think its valid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `perltex` should be

```
perltex --latex=pdflatex <filename>
```

With TeXworks you can define a new tool, here's the relevant window

[image]

I don't think there's a way to pass options to `pdflatex`, such as `-synctex=1` or `-shell-escape`.