# How to use \varepsilon as default

Tags: fonts

I am writing a document, and I used `\epsilon` throughout. I would really like to change it to `\varepsilon`, but manually it would be quite a struggle.

So the question is whether I can put something in the preamble so that `\epsilon` actually give the same output as `\varepsilon`.

I tried with `\newcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}`, but it didn't work (I imagine because `\epsilon` is an already defined command). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`

Comment: `\let\epsilonTMP\epsilon\let\epsilon\varepsilon\let\varepsilon\epsilonTMP` after that `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon` should be switched.

Comment: By help of editor *\find/replace* function you can simple replace all `epsilon` with `\varepsilon` in your document. I would not give new meaning to `\epsilon` ...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Indeed, `\epsilon` is already defined.

In this case it's safe to do

```
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
```

<sup>I know that `\let\epsilon\varepsilon` would be slightly more efficient, but it's not for beginners.</sup>

Note that in this way you have no way to recover the original `\epsilon` symbol, but that should not be a problem. In case you need the original, you need to save its meaning, so you can do

```
\let\uglyepsilon\epsilon
\let\epsilon\varepsilon
```

(choose a different name than `\uglyepsilon`, if you so prefer). Now using `\epsilon` or `\varepsilon` in the document will produce *ε*, while `\uglyepsilon` will produce *ϵ*. For this purpose, `\let` is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Comment: +1 for "\uglyepsilon"

Comment: @JetChung Did you catch that I don't like it? 

Comment: Isn't the opposite of `\varepsilion` `\constepsilon`??

Comment: @alephzero Here “var” stands for “variant” `;-)`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say that `\let\epsilon\varepsilon`is "not for beginners"?

Comment: @chsk The `\let` command is not documented in the LaTeX manual and using it might lead to issues (not in this particular case, though); see, for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387897/4427 (where even seasoned programmers got wrong).