# Command that returns current font size as a length?

Tags: macros, fontsize

I need a way to get the current fontsize as a length.

I hope I didn't overlook anything that already provides this. What I found that I can do

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsize}
\setlength{\fsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
```

but it will be set to a fixed length that does not update when font size changes.

Now I tried to put it into a command:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsizeb}
\setlength{\fsizeb}{\f@size pt}
\newcommand\fsize{\fizeb}
\makeatother
```

(still works as a length but also does not update - not sure if this is actually valid, maybe this is my first fault)

And finally I tried

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fsizeb}
\newcommand\fsize{%
    \setlength{\fsizeb}{\f@size pt}%
    \fsizeb%
}
```

which fails and does not seem to return a length.

I assume I'm doing something horribly wrong (I'm quite new to this part of LaTeX, so I hope you can tell me wether what I want is at all possible and give me some pointers how to implement...)

---

As for why I (think to) need this:
I want to be able to set `\baselineskip` to a specific multiple of the font size (similarly as the `line-height` property works in CSS/SVG) like so (with the solution suggested by Manuel in the comments):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{1\fsize}
\verb=\setlength{\baselineskip}{1\fsize}= -- line-height: 1; bars touching exactly\\\textbar\\\textbar

\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.25\fsize}
\verb=\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.25\fsize}= -- line-height: 1.25; (relative to font-size)\\\textbar\\\textbar

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there are yet easier solutions I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: why can you not use `\f@size` as it is, why do you need to use a dimen register? (if you use a register you are going to have to patch `\selectfont` to update the register every time anything changes but it is hard to think why you would need this)

Comment: I would use  just `\makeatletter\newcommand\fsize{\f@size pt}\makeatother`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Or if he actually needs a “length” may be `\newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}`? Although I don't know what could be the case.

Comment: @Manuel This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you (feel free to add it as an answer)! I added an explanation on what I want to do with it and why I want to have the result as a length.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}
\makeatother
```

This way you can use the macro like `\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.33\fsize}`.

Comment: My favourite answer.

Answer (score 9):

`\selectfont` is the switch the changes the font. You can tie into this and update `\fsize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newlength{\fsize}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764
\LetLtxMacro\oldselectfont\selectfont
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\selectfont}{\oldselectfont\setlength{\fsize}{\f@size pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tiny\the\fsize

\scriptsize\the\fsize

\footnotesize\the\fsize

\small\the\fsize

\normalsize\the\fsize

\large\the\fsize

\Large\the\fsize

\LARGE\the\fsize

\Huge\the\fsize

\end{document}
```

Comment: Confirmed working. The solution posted by Manuel in the comments is a lot more concise, though.

Answer (score 8):

If you set the length, it won't change until you reset it. What you need is a macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentfsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
```

Example (using the code by Werner):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentfsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\newdimen\fsize
\newcommand{\setfsize}{\setlength{\fsize}{\currentfsize}}

\begin{document}

\setfsize % should be 10pt

\tiny\currentfsize

\scriptsize\currentfsize

\footnotesize\currentfsize

\small\currentfsize

\normalsize\currentfsize

\large\currentfsize

\Large\currentfsize

\LARGE\currentfsize

\Huge\currentfsize

\the\fsize % should be 10pt (printed in \Huge size)

\end{document}
```

As you see, setting `\fsize` at the beginning doesn't change its value.

[image]

Comment: This does not give a length - as I want to be able to write e.g. `1.25\fsize` that does not completely solve my problem.

Comment: `1.25\dimexpr\currentfsize\relax`