# Fontsize within tables and theads

Tags: tables, fontsize

Assuming the case that I would like to change the `font-size` of the table given below with adding `\Large` to the beginning of the `table`.

[image]

Somehow this doesn't apply to the theads and so the font size differs.
One obvious solution is to go into every thead and add `\Large` ->

```
\thead{\Large Text1 and \\ \Large Text2} & A & B\\
```

Might there be a single line solution or lets say a proper way of doing it as it is getting quite annoying after some changes, e.g. in a bigger `table`?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}    

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{table}
\Large % for demonstration purpose 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\thead{Text1 and \\ Text2} & A & B\\
\midrule
C & \thead{1\\and 1}& 2 \\
D & 3 & \thead{4\\ and 4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}} \quad

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409956

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentfsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother

\newdimen\fsize
\newcommand{\setfsize}{\setlength{\fsize}{\currentfsize}}


\begin{document}    

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{table}
\Large % for demonstration purpose 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\setfsize}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\thead{Text1 and \\ Text2} & A & B\\
\midrule
C & \thead{1\\and 1}& 2 \\
D & 3 & \thead{4\\ and 4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}} \quad

\end{document}
```

Comment: Funfact: One can't accept answers within six minutes. Thanks!