# \let on macro defined by \newcommand with optional argument

Tags: macros, tex-core, optional-arguments

Suppose we have

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][optional]{#1 #2}
```

defined somewhere (e.g. some package) and want to redefine it and re-use the original definition. This usually works with `\let` like described in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/let:

```
\let\originalfoo\foo
\renewcommand{\foo}[2][optional]{\originalfoo[#1]{modified #2}}
```

However, this leads to an infinite loop, as `\let` does not handle the optional argument.

How to handle the optional argument defined by `\newcommand` with `\let`?

Comment: FYI, I have a hack/workaround for it, but I would find it nicer, if copying by `\let` would workout somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro This other question is somehow the other way round and hard to find if you have the problem explained (the problem here is one case of an answer in the link; the answer here is the problem stated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual `\let` does not work with macros having optional arguments. You need `\LetLtxMacro` from `letltxmacro` package in order to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcommand{\foo}[2][optional]{#1 #2}

\LetLtxMacro{\originalfoo}{\foo}

\renewcommand{\foo}[2][optional]{\originalfoo[#1]{modified #2}}


\begin{document}
\originalfoo[Hello]{World}

\foo[Hello]{World}
\end{document}
```