# Pagenumber within \cref command

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, pageref

I am writing a script for a lecture in math and have quite a few cross-references in it. Now i have the problem, that the cross-references are sometimes pretty far away from the theorems they refer to. I would like to have a way (by options of the `cleveref` package or a renewcommand for `\cref`) to put the page number into the output of `\cref`. I've alredy tried a `\renewcommand` like

```
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{\namecref{#1} \labelcref{#1} (\cpageref{#1})}
```

but I have also some references to more than one label. The problem with this renewcommand is that `\nameref{}` takes only one label and so after the change I get some "??" in my document. I could possibly go through the whole document again and add the page ref everywhere it is needed, but this would take a lot of time and I would appreciate it, if there would be a more easy way. It would also be great if the page ref could only be given if the label is on a different page than the cross-reference call-out (if this is even possible). I've searched the Internet now for quite a while and didn't find an answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance for your efforts

PS: the document class is `article`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheoremstyle{thm}   {\topsep}{\topsep}{\itshape}{-0.25em}{\bfseries}{}{0.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{thm}
    \newtheorem {theorem}   {Theorem}[section]

\Crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}

\begin{document}
    \section{Something}
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{Theorem_1}
        Some theorem.
        \begin{equation}
            a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
        \end{equation}
    \end{theorem}
    maybe some other text
    \begin{theorem}
        \label{Theorem}
        Soem other theorem.
    \end{theorem}
    A reference to \cref{Theorem} everything is great
    \newpage
    If I put a reference here to \cref{Theorem_1} I would prefer it would be like \cref{Theorem_1} (\cpageref{Theorem_1}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable code we can play with ...

Comment: You should capitalise `theorem` and `Theorems` in the second and third argument of `\Crefname`. Otherwise the word won't be capitalised if you use `\Cref` (at the start of a sentence, say). Incidentally, you don't even have to declare the theorem environment since `cleveref` already knows about theorems, lemmas (unless you prefer lemmata as a plural), corollaries, definitions, propositions, results, examples, remarks and notes.

Comment: I wasn't shure what I need to declare and what I don't. I write the skript in german and in the script I declared everything the way I need it. This was just for the example but thats not really the matter. But thanks for the mention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and its `\vref` macro pretty much do what you're looking to accomplish.

Note that if both `varioref` and `cleveref` are loaded, `varioref` *must* be loaded before `cleveref`. If both packages are loaded, the command `\vref` acts very much like `\cref`, except that it automatically inserts a page number reference (as well as the main cross-reference) whenever the call-out and the cross-referenced item aren't located on the same page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheoremstyle{thm}   {\topsep}{\topsep}{\itshape}{-0.25em}{\bfseries}{}{0.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{thm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

%\Crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
%\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{theorem} \label{Theorem_1}
Some theorem.
\begin{equation} a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1} \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
Maybe some other text
\begin{theorem}\label{Theorem_2}
Some other theorem.
\end{theorem}

A cross-reference to \cref{Theorem_2}---everything is great.

\newpage \null \newpage

I would like a cross-reference of the form ``\vref{Theorem_1}''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what i want. But with this solution I still have the problem that I have to go through over 100 output pages again and need to change every \cref to a \vref. And my sourcecode is in multiple parts so i would also need to change those all the time. If there isn't a nice way to reach what I want I just might have to do this but I would prefer an easy global solution in wich I dont have to change every single reference.

Comment: @Kai - Since i have virtually no information about the structure of your document, it's not possible for me to make a recommendation for how you should organize your document's cross-references. If this were my document, I would either replace `\cref` with `\vref` for the most important theorems only or, more likely, load the `hyperref` package, automatically making all cross-reference call-outs into hyperlinks to the corresponding targets. (If you go this route, be sure load `varioref` first, `hyperref` second, and `cleveref` third, i.e., last.)

Comment: I have the hyperref loaded and in use. But I prefer to lern with a printed script and in this case I have to search pretty much. But thanks for the help and if nothing else comes up I will go through the whole document. I just thougth I ask incase someone already had this problem and found a good and easy solution. Thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: If you absolutely must, you can redefine `\cref` to behave as `\vref*` (the starred version is preferable, see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/varioref.pdf)) with `\renewcommand*\cref{\vref*}`. Doing a global search-and-replace doesn't seem like it should be that difficult though. If you need to store the original `\cref` you should use [`\LetLtxMacro`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/156366).

Comment: @Mico I desided to take your method and change the ´\cref´ to ´\vref´...this isn't as much work as I thought thanks to the search mechanism in TeX-Maker. Thanks a lot :)