# Empty optional argument or Not giving optional argument at all?

Tags: xparse, parbox

I learnt that `\parbox` has five arguments, that is: `\parbox[<align>][<height>][<inner-align>]{<width>}{<text>}`. So I constrcut my own \myparbox in which I add `\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}` before #5. But it fails. What's the reason and how to re-define \myparbox?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myparbox}{ooomm}{%
  \parbox[#1][#2][#3]{#4}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#5}
}
\begin{document}
AAA\fbox{\parbox[][][]{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}AAA\\% parbox typesets nothing. why?
BBB\fbox{\myparbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB% This fails to compile
\end{document}
```

***EDIT:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldparbox\parbox
\RenewDocumentCommand{\parbox}{sO{c}oO{t}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}
        {\oldparbox[#2]{#5}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#6}}
        {\oldparbox[#2][#3][#4]{#5}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#6}}
    }
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}
        {\oldparbox[#2]{#5}{#6}}
        {\oldparbox[#2][#3][#4]{#5}{#6}}
    } 
}
\begin{document}\the\fboxsep
AAA\fbox{\parbox[t]{8em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii}}AAA\\% parbox typesets nothing why?.
BBB\fbox{\parbox*{6em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB% This fails to compile
\end{document}
```

Comment: An empty optional argument `[]` is not always the same as not giving an optional argument at all. Compare `\parbox[][]{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}` and `\parbox[]{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}`. In the `xparse` example things get worse because `o`'s `#1` becomes the special value `-noValue-` when no optional argument is given. Naturally `\parbox` can't deal with that.

Comment: I know that the default value of #1 is [c],  #3 is [t], but what is the default value of #2 which can be used to define \myparbox?

Comment: Instead of worrying about the defaults, it might just be better to run three test cases and run `\parbox` in three different ways. Then you do not need to know about the kernel defaults. Use say `\IfNoValueTF{#1}{true}{false}` and nest several of these.

Comment: According to suggest above , I edited my MWE, but can not pass compile. why?

Comment: as I said when you asked in comments under your previous question, there is no value that you can pass to the optional argument that is equivalent to not using the argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments, an empty optional argument `[]` need not be equivalent to giving no optional argument at all. Whether not giving the argument is equivalent to passing a particular value must be checked with the documentation or implementation of the command.

In the example things get worse because `xparse`'s optional `o` argument actually contain the special marked value `-NoValue-` if the corresponding optional argument was not given. You can and should test for presence of a value with `\IfNoValueTF` (as suggested by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)'s comment).

That is a very viable solution when you have only one optional argument to deal with, but it gets messy if the number of arguments increases.

In case of `\parbox` you can find out that the default arguments are `c`, `\relax` as special marker and `s` when you look up the definition in `sourc2e.pdf`.

So you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myparbox}{O{c}O{\relax}O{s}mm}{%
  \parbox[#1][#2][#3]{#4}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#5}%
}
\begin{document}
BBB\fbox{\parbox{4em}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB

BBB\fbox{\myparbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB
\end{document}
```

Normally I would try to work around issues like this that require me to know the default optional argument values/behaviour and or need a great number of `\IfNoValueTF` tests to get the arguments right as the first method seems fragile and the second very verbose and repetitive. An approach similar to [Marijn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476003/35864) might be an alternative, but at least in this case also requires intimate knowledge of the definition of `\parbox`.

---

*edit*: I only just saw the new version of the question. `\let` is not enough for robust commands with optional arguments: [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/35864). I would also strongly suggest not to redefine fundamental commands such as `\parbox` even if the implementation might be backwards compatible. A new name is much safer.

Comment: I  followed your answer and edited my MWE, but failed. Could you please have look at my edited MWE?

Comment: @lyl That won't work because of the `\let`, see the *edit* bit of my answer. I could get something working with `letltxmacro` that compiles, but there is a weird side-effect. Try with `\usepackage{letltxmacro}\LetLtxMacro{\oldparbox}{\parbox}` instead of `\let\oldparbox\parbox`. It is a really bad idea to redefine such a fundamental command.

Comment: @lyl Don't! Redefining the original `\parbox` will not end well...

Comment: @lyl  From where do you have information that `\parbox` supports `\partbox*`? That is probably why you cannot get `\LetLtxMacro` to work. As far as I can see from the sources `\parbox` does not support a star, so `\oldparbox*{4em}{....}` fails as it tries to use `*` as a length

Comment: I just use  `[s]` argument provided by `xparse` as a test to  distinguish my parbox from the original `\parbox`. I think this is not a good idea as suggested in comments.

Comment: @ moewe for `\parbox`, what's the difference between `O{\relax}` and `O{}`?

Comment: @lyl The difference is that `O{}` leaves `#2` empty if the argument wasn't given and `O{\relax}` leaves `\relax` in `#2`. In theory the two can have different behaviour (trivially if the macro says `\detokenize{#2}`), but in this case a short test and a tentative look at the code suggest they do the same here. I used `\relax` because that was used in the original implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `xpatch` to insert the extra code at the right place in the command, without the need to pass variables around. The `\parbox` command calls the internal `\@iiiparbox` command which processes the actual contents, so this internal command is the one that should be patched. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@iiiparbox}{#5}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#5}{}{}
\makeatother
AAA\fbox{\parbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}AAA
\end{document}
```

Note that this changes the behavior of all parboxes. If you want a custom command with the justified alignment and also keep the regular command, then you can define the custom command using a copy of the `\@iiiparbox` command and patch the copy instead of the original. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\myparbox{\@ifnextchar [\@iparbox {\myiiiparbox c\relax [s]}}
\let\myiiiparbox\@iiiparbox
\xpatchcmd{\myiiiparbox}{#5}{\sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#5}{}{} 
\makeatother
AAA\fbox{\parbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}AAA

BBB\fbox{\myparbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution with xpatch, I'll be learning this package.

Answer (score 2):

The optional arguments to `\parbox` must contain specific tokens, if present. The default value for the first is `c`, so we can spare some checks for the presence of the optional arguments. One needs to start from the last one.

The first optional argument should be `c` (default), `t` or `b`; the second one should be a length; the last one should be `c`, `t`, `b` or `s` (if not given, the first one is used).

Note that the last argument to `\myparbox` should by denoted by `+m`, in order to be able to input different paragraphs. The `\deliverparbox` macro is used in order to minimize code duplication.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myparbox}{O{c}oom+m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {%
      \parbox[#1]{#4}{\deliverparbox{#5}}%
     }%
     {%
      \parbox[#1][#2]{#4}{\deliverparbox{#5}}%
     }%
   }%
   {%
    \parbox[#1][#2][#3]{#4}{\deliverparbox{#5}}%
   }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\deliverparbox}{+m}{%
  \sloppy\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}#1%
}

\begin{document}

AAA\fbox{\parbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}AAA

BBB\fbox{\myparbox{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff}}BBB

BBB\fbox{\myparbox[t][12ex][s]{4em}{aa bb cc dd ee ff\par\vfil aa bb}}BBB

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +m is a much much valuable reminder which I have not think of!

Comment: For `\IfNoValueTF{#2}`, the only diference between its two branches is whether #2 is given to \parbox. So, is there a way writing code like this: `\parbox[#1] \if...{}{[#2]}{#4}{#5}` .

Comment: @lyl Depending on what the optional argument is expected to contain, there can be; not in this case.