# Macro only to be defined in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I often use short macros in mathematical formulas for frequently used symbols, e.g. `\d x` for a differential dx or, say, `\v` if I need a vector **v** very often in my text to make things more readable.
However, I get a clash with predefined macros because `\d` stands for a dot under the next character and `v` for the hacek accent, which I don't want to override (maybe I need them in the bibliography...).

So, I came up with the following to override those macros only in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everyhook}
\newcommand{\mathdef}[2]{%
  \PushPostHook{math}{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}%
  \PushPostHook{display}{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}}
\mathdef{d}{\mathrm{d}}%

\begin{document}
  \d x  is an x with a dot below and $\int f(x) \d x$ is an integral over $x$.
\end{document}
```

However, I would like the command to be defined like normal macros too, i.e. `\mathdef{\d}{\mathrm{d}}`, and also be able to take arguments, but all my experiments with `expandafter`, `unexpanded`, etc. didn't work out and led only to the usual strange error messages. Any hint how I can do that?

Furthermore, do you think there is a big performance penalty using `\everymath` like that in a large document?

Comment: You can just use `#1` for the macro: `\newcommand{\mathdef}[2]{%
  \PushPostHook{math}{\def#1{#2}}%
  \PushPostHook{display}{\def#1{#2}}}` and then use `\mathdef{\d}{\mathrm{d}}`, it is not required to use `\csname` here.

Comment: Of course the easiest way to avoid problems is to choose different macro names, e.g., `\md` for a differential. Or, especially for short substitutions, don't use macros at all, because they make the text less readable, for example `\vec v` or `\vec{v}` are immediately clear to yourself and possibly others, while for `\v` you need to remember or look up the definition somewhere - and it is not _that_ much extra typing.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, you're right. Probably I had another error in my original document and drew the wrong conclusions...

Comment: @Marijn I know, but I do not want that. First, `\md` for the differential is not really mnemonic, and maybe trying to do this in a consistent way, you run into other clashes. Second, writing explicitly `\vec v` and stuff like that is usually ok for short documents (and I do that myself), but for longer ones and long formulas it can become cumbersome. Sometimes, you don't see the formula anymore for all the `\vec`s, `\mathbb`s, `\mathcal`s and so on, and I also find it annoying when I want to put the variable into a sub- or superscript and I always have to enclose it in curly braces.

Comment: In the orthogonal direction to Martin's suggestion, I rename some of the “accent” commands to use them for math instead.  For instance `\let\Hungarumlaut\H\renewcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}`  My thinking is that I don't use the Hungarumlaut that much, so it isn't too much of an inconvenience to type `Erd\Hungarumlaut os`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My idea is very similar to egreg's, but I'd like to add an optional argument, so the math command could process arguments itself. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mathdef}{mO{0}m}{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old\string#1\endcsname=#1
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname new\string#1\endcsname[#2]{#3}
  \DeclareRobustCommand#1{%
    \ifmmode
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\next\csname new\string#1\endcsname
    \else
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\next\csname old\string#1\endcsname
    \fi
    \next
  }%
}

\mathdef{\v}[1]{\tilde{#1}}
\mathdef{\d}{\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
Ha\v{c}ek and tilde $\v{a}+\v{b}=1$.

\d x  is an x with a dot below and $\int f(x) \d x$ is an integral over $x$.
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Would you try `$\begin{array}{c}\v{a}\end{array}$`?

Comment: @egreg: You're right. It fails horribly. I've replaced `\renewcommand` by `\DeclareRobustCommand` which seems to fix it. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @egreg and Sergei: It seems that there is an issue with \S. Could you please have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578008/24048?

Answer (score 7):

I would not use `\everymath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathdef}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{\@mathdef@new{#1}{#2}}{\@mathdef@remember{#1}{#2}}
}

\newcommand{\@mathdef@remember}[2]{%
  \expandafter\LetLtxMacro
    \csname textmode@#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname mathmode@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \ifmmode\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
     {\csname mathmode@#1\endcsname}{\csname textmode@#1\endcsname}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\@mathdef@new}[2]{%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\mathdef{d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\d{x} is an x with a dot below and $\int f(x) \d x$ is an integral over $x$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't think this is a good way to go, though. It's confusing and prone to errors.

See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/4427) for information about `\LetLtxMacro`.

It's a bit easier with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathdef}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{\@mathdef@new{#1}{#2}}{\@mathdef@remember{#1}{#2}}
}

\newcommand{\@mathdef@remember}[2]{%
  \expandafter\robustify\csname#1\endcsname
  \csletcs{textmode@#1}{#1}%
  \csdef{mathmode@#1}{#2}%
  \protected\csdef{#1}{%
    \ifmmode\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
     {\csuse{mathmode@#1}}{\csuse{textmode@#1}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\@mathdef@new}[2]{%
  \protected\csdef{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\mathdef{d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\d{x} is an x with a dot below and $\int f(x) \d x$ is an integral over $x$.

\end{document}
```

Why do I use `\DeclareRobustCommand` (first version) or `\protected` (second version) all around?

When TeX does a write operation it is in no mode at all, in particular it is not in math mode. A simplistic definition such as

```
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \relax % if this comes first in an alignment
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \foo@math\foo@text
}
```

would *always* choose `\foo@text` if found in a `\write`. The above protections make the `\mathdef` commands to write themselves, so no choice is made at `\write` time.

Why not using `\everymath`? Try the following example and see.

```
\documentclass{article}

\everymath{\let\foo\foomath}
\newcommand{\foo}{Foo}
\newcommand{\foomath}{Ops}

\begin{document}

Text: \foo

Math: $\foo$

Ops: abc\textsuperscript{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks egreg. Learned a lot from your answer. Still I would go with Sergei's answer, because it's a bit more concise.
Just two small questions: Why wouldn't you go with `everymath`? Efficiency, because all the definitions have to be executed for every little formula ? Or is it more because of robustness? 
And, did you mean `\ifmmode` in the example?

Comment: @ElmarZander Yes, efficiency is the main reason. But not the only one, see the addition.

Answer (score 2):

You wish to use the `\PushPostHook`-macro from the **everyhook**-package for (re)defining macros that process arguments?

**Issue 1:**

In LaTeX arguments are denoted by `#1` and `#2` and the like, i.e., by sequences of hashes trailed by a digit in the range 1..9.

When it comes to nesting definitions, hashes need to be doubled for the inner definitions:

```
\def\outsidemacro#1{%
  \def\insidemacro##1{This is insidemacro's argument: ##1.}%  
  This is outsidemacro's argument: #1.%
}
```

During expansion, two consecutive hashes will be collapsed into one hash, i.e., the amount of hashes will be halved.

I.e., `\outsidemacro{foo}` yields:

```
\def\insidemacro#1{This is insidemacro's argument: #1.}%  
This is outsidemacro's argument: foo.%
```

Looking at the definition of `\PushPostHook` via `\show\PushPostHook` yields:

```
> \PushPostHook=\protected\long macro:
#1#2->\eh@checkhook {#1}\PushPostHook \letcs \eh@tempi {eh@post#1}\expandafter 
\gdef \csname eh@post#1\expandafter \endcsname \expandafter {\eh@tempi \eh@hook
separator #2}\undef \eh@tempi .
```

As you can see, the tokens are kept in macros whose names are of pattern 
`\eh@post⟨name of hook⟩`.

E.g., `\eh@postmath` and  `\eh@postdisplay`.

For adding tokens to such a macro, `\PushPostHook` lets the macro in question equal to `\eh@tempi` and then redefines the macro in question by appending the tokens in question behind the **expansion** of `\eh@tempi`.

Expanding `\eh@tempi` is a crucial point:

In case the definition of `\eh@tempi` contains hashes (`#`), during expansion two consecutive hashes will collapse into one of them.

This implies:

Whenever `\PushPostHook` is called for adding things to `\eh@postmath` or `\eh@postdisplay`, the amount of consecutive hashes with things that are already in `\eh@postmath` or `\eh@postdisplay` will be halved.

This will be a problem especially when calling `\PushPostHook` several times for adding things to `\eh@postmath` or `\eh@postdisplay`.

You can avoid the halving of the amount of consecutive hashes by maintaining things by means of a token register because when the content of a token register is "spit out" via `\the`, the amount of hashes will not be reduced. When "spitting out" due to `\the` takes place during `\edef`, the amount of hashes will not only be not reduced but it will be doubled.

If you do, e.g.,

```
\myscratchtoks{#}
\edef\mymacro{\the\myscratchtoks}
```

, in the definition of `\mymacro` the amount of hashes coming from `\myscratchtoks` will be doubled. When expanding `\mymacro`, that doubled amount will be halved and thus the expansion of `\mymacro` delivers the same amount of hashes as would be delivered by `\the\myscratchtoks`.

Therefore I suggest adding things to a token-register and using  `\PushPostHook` only for "flushing" that token-register.

**Issue 2:**

If you wish to maintain macros that can also process arguments, I suggest implementing something that can be used similarly to the prefixes `\long` or `\global`.

In the example below I used `#{`-notation for implementing a macro `\mathcommand` which processes left-brace-delimited arguments that are trailed by brace-nested arguments. As the `⟨definition text⟩` of a macro always is to be nested in braces, you can use the processing of left-brace-delimited-arguments for fetching all tokens that come before a `⟨definition text⟩`.
Such tokens can be the definition-command itself (e.g., `\renewcommand*` or `\global\long\def`), the control-sequence-token that is to be (re)defined, and the `⟨parameter text⟩`.

E.g., with

```
\mathcommand\renewcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]{%
  \mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1) 
  \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2)
}%
```

, `\mathcommand`'s first (left-brace-delimited) argument will be the sequence `\renewcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]` and
its second argument is formed by the stuff that is nested inside braces: `\mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1) \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2)`.
`\mathcommand` will add the sequence `⟨first argument⟩{⟨second argument⟩}`, i.e., the sequence `\renewcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]{\mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1) \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2) }` to the token-register `\mymathhooktoks`.

I also implemented a macro `\mathcommandfromname` which also fetches a left-brace-delimited argument and takes the stuff that is behind that argument and that therefore is nested in braces for the name of a control-sequence-token which can be formed via `\csname..\endcsname`:

E.g.,

```
\mathcommandfromname\renewcommand*{mymacrowitharguments}[2]{%
  \mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1) 
  \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2)
}%
```

yields:

```
\mathcommand\renewcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]{%
  \mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1) 
  \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2)
}%
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everyhook}

\newtoks\myscratchtoks
\newcommand\mymathhookmacro{}%

\PushPostHook{math}{\mymathhookmacro}%
\PushPostHook{display}{\mymathhookmacro}%

\newcommand{\mathcommand}{}%
\long\def\mathcommand#1#{\innermathcommand{#1}}%
\newcommand{\innermathcommand}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\myscratchtoks\expandafter{\mymathhookmacro#1{#2}}%
  \xdef\mymathhookmacro{\the\myscratchtoks}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\mathcommandfromname{}%
\long\def\mathcommandfromname#1#{\romannumeral0\innermathcommandfromname{#1}}%
\newcommand\innermathcommandfromname[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ \mathcommand#1}%
}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]{%
  non-math-arg~1: \textbf{(#1)} %
  non-math-arg~2: \textbf{(#2)}%
}%

\mathcommand\renewcommand*\mymacrowitharguments[2]{%
  \mbox{math-arg~1: }(#1)
  \mbox{ math-arg~2: }(#2)
}%

\newcommand*\myothermacrowitharguments[2]{%
  other-non-math-arg~1: \textbf{(#1)} %
  other-non-math-arg~2: \textbf{(#2)}%
}%

\mathcommandfromname\renewcommand*{myothermacrowitharguments}[2]{%
  \mbox{other-math-arg~1: }(#1)
  \mbox{ other-math-arg~2: }(#2)
}%

\mathcommand\renewcommand*\d{\mathrm{d}}%

\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}

\d x  is an x with a dot below and $\int f(x) \d x$ is an 
integral over $x$.

\bigskip

Testing with \verb|\mymacrowitharguments|:\smallskip

outside math:\\
\mymacrowitharguments{arg A}{arg B}
\smallskip

inside math:\\
$\mymacrowitharguments{arg A}{arg B}$
\bigskip

Testing with \verb|\myothermacrowitharguments|:\smallskip

outside math:\\
\myothermacrowitharguments{arg A}{arg B}
\smallskip

inside math:\\
$\myothermacrowitharguments{arg A}{arg B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the information. Actually, I didn't /wish/ to use `PushPostHook`, it was just the only thing I could come up with. I still do not quite understand the `#1#` notation. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @ElmarZander It should be `#{`-notation - sorry. It was discussed yesterday in [What is “# Notation”? How does the # syntax work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477537/118714)