# Package dutchcal and \let command are not playing together as I expected

Tags: fonts, packages, mathcal

Given the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\tempcal \mathcal
\usepackage{dutchcal}
\let\dutchcal\mathcal
\let\mathcal\tempcal

\begin{document}
\(\dutchcal H~~~\mathcal H~~~\tempcal H\)
\end{document}
```

I expected the compiled document to have the latter two H's be in the original `\mathcal` format, but when I compile all three are the `\dutchcal` version.

**The Desire:**  I would like to apply standard `\mathcal` to upper case letters, and use (an appropriately defined) `\dutchcal` on lower case letters.  When I tried the above, the upper case font was overwritten, even though `\let` was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\let` alone is not enough here, because the involved commands have a more complicated internal structure with helper macros, whose definitions would also have to be copied over. Apparently not even `\LetLtxMacro` ([When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/35864)) is quite enough here.

Luckily, [`dutchcal.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/dutchcal/tex/latex/dutchcal/dutchcal.sty) is not very long and the relevant bits can be easily copied to your document preamble and modified

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\dutchcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\dutchcal}{bold}{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\dutchbcal} {U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\(\dutchcal{H} \quad \mathcal{H}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Two "H"s one in <code>\dutchal</code> and one in <code>\mathcal</code>]