# Change function argument globally in renewcommand

Tags: hyperref

I want to set one argument of a function permanently to a specific value.
In my case it is the function `\TextField` which has the argument `bordercolor`. I want to set it globally to "nothing" instead of writing `\TextField[bordercolor=,name=xyz]` everytime.
This was my attempt which leads to an error:
`\renewcommand{\TextField}{\TextField[bordercolor=]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\TEXTFIELD\TextField
\renewcommand\TextField[1][]{\TEXTFIELD[bordercolor=,#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=xy]{foo}
\TextField[bordercolor=red,name=xy]{bar}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works fine! Could you explain line 4 and 5 and why you need "TEXTFIELD"?

Comment: It holds the original definition of `\TextField`. We need it to prevent a recursion.

Comment: Since `\TextField` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, `\let\TEXTFIELD\TextField` is dangerous. Load `\usepackage{letltxmacro}` and do `\LetLtxMacro\TEXTFIELD\TextField` instead. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001).

Answer (score 2):

hyperref has a command to which you can append default keys for the textfield (by default it contains only "print"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd\DefaultOptionsofText{,bordercolor=}{}{\fail}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=xy]{foo}
\TextField[bordercolor=red,name=xy]{bar}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The alternative is to simply set the key with `\kvsetkeys` (this will affect the border of other field types too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\kvsetkeys{Field}{bordercolor=}

\TextField[name=x]{foo}
\TextField[bordercolor=red,name=y]{bar}


\end{Form}
\end{document}
```