# Relabeling commands before redefining them

Tags: macros, symbols

I would like to rename a couple of commands so that the commands match the words I think of when I want to use them.

I would like to have `\iso` be what is by default `\cong` (an equals sign with a `\sim` on top: ≅), and I would like `\cong` to be what `\equiv` is by default (3 parallel lines: ≡).

Currently, I have in my preamble:

```
\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}
\renewcommand{\cong}{\equiv}
```

This does not work. It changes `\cong` to "≡", but is also makes `\iso` print a "≡". I find this confusing because my understanding was that TeX read commands from top to bottom, so I assumed it would assign `\iso` to `\cong` before overwriting the definition of `\cong`.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

(PS. I'm not sure what tags are appropriate for this. Let me know if this should be categorized differently.)

Comment: Your reasoning is almost correct. However `\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}` does not make `\iso` _equal to_ `\cong`, it makes `\iso` _expand to_ `\cong`. But when you use `\iso` (which expands to `\cong`), `\cong` will typeset the `\equiv` symbol. Which is what you're seeing. What you want is `\let\iso\cong` and `\let\cong\equiv`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik beware robust commands when using \let:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what do you mean?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course what I meant to say was: "What you want is to load `letltxmacro` and use `\LetLtxMacro\iso\cong` and `\LetLtxMacro\cong\equiv`. " ;-)

Comment: @rosterherik sorry that was aimed at Phelype who would know once reminded. better to use `\LetLtxMacro` from the letltxmacro package rather than `\let`

Comment: So, the conclusion from the above comments is you need to add `\usepackage{letltxmacro}` in the preamable and then `\LetLtxMacro\iso\cong` and `\LetLtxMacro\cong\equiv` as @PhelypeOleinik  said. This copies the definition of `\cong` into `\iso`, so that when you _later_ change `\cong`, the definition of `\iso` is not effected. For more info on `\LetLtxMacro` see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill thank you for the comprehensive answer. If you write it below I will accept it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Please post an answer so we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to load the `letltxmacro` package and do:

```latex
\LetLtxMacro\iso\cong
\LetLtxMacro\cong\equiv
```

---

A little explanation: your reasoning that "TeX read commands from top to bottom" is correct. After you do `\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}`, the command `\iso` will make a `≅` as you expect, but not *how* you expect it to. After the `\newcommand` above (I'm ignoring the redefinition of `\cong` for now), every time TeX sees the control sequence `\iso` it will know that `\iso` should *expand to* `\cong`, *i.e.,* when `\iso` is found it is *replaced* by `\cong`. After the replacement is done, TeX sees `\cong`, which will (for now) make a `≅`. So far so good.

However, now you do `\renewcommand{\cong}{\equiv}`. Same as defore, this tells TeX that every time it finds the control sequence `\cong`, it should expand to (or: be replaced by) `\equiv`. If you use `\cong` now you get the `≡` symbol as you wanted. However if you use `\iso`, TeX expands it to `\cong`, which is then again expanded to `\equiv`, which still prints a `≡`. Once TeX expanded a control sequence it has no memory of what it was. This means that whether you use `\iso` and it expands to `\cong` or you use `\cong` directly, for TeX it will be the same thing.

---

Of course, what you meant was to have `\iso` be *equal to* `\cong` and then `\cong` be *equal to* `\equiv`. The TeX operation to do this is `\let`, not `\def` (`\def` is the underlying primitive in `\(re)newcommand`).

After you do `\let\iso\cong`, when TeX finds `\iso` it does not expand to `\cong`, but to what `\cong` was at the time you did the `\let` operation. (Very, *very*) roughly speaking, `\let\iso\cong` would have the same effect as `\newcommand\iso{<meaning of \cong>}`. So it doesn't matter if you change the meaning of `\cong` (with either `\let` or `\def`), `\iso` already has a copy of it so it's safe.

---

But there's a catch: various LaTeX commands are "robust". This means that the meaning of `\cong` is `\protect\cong⎵` (that's right, it is the command `\cong⎵`, with a trailing space in the name; you can't easily access it) (there are other protection mechanisms, for example `\protect\\cong`, with `\\` in the command name, but the moral is the same).

So even if you do `\let\cong\equiv`, the meaning of the internal `\cong⎵` will remain unchanged, and things can quickly go off tracks.

So the same warning that goes for using `\def` with LaTeX applies to `\let`: don't use it, unless you are very sure of what you're doing and you are ready to face the consequence of any misuse :-)

If you are not sure, use the `letltxmacro` package, which provides you a safer version of `\let` which takes care of robust macros and does the right thing when they are robust. Note the difference of doing `\let\iso\cong`:

```latex
> \iso=macro:
->\protect \cong  .
l.4 \show\iso

?
```

and using `\LetLtxMacro\iso\cong`:

```latex
> \iso=macro:
->\protect \iso  .
l.4 \show\iso

?
```