# How to pass custom commands to LetLtxMacro?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I think it's fairly common to [redefine macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001).
And I'm creating two functions to help storing and restoring these redefined macros.

And so I tried using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storecommand}[1]
    {%
        \LetLtxMacro{\\env@#1}{\\#1}%
    }
\newcommand{\restorecommand}[1]
    {%
        \LetLtxMacro{\\#1}{\\env@#1}%
    }
\makeatother

% Example usage

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \makeatletter
    Expected:\\
    \newcommand{\foo}{bar}%
    \foo\\
    \LetLtxMacro{\env@foo}{\foo}%
    \renewcommand{\foo}{baz}%
    \foo\\
    \LetLtxMacro{\foo}{\env@foo}%
    \foo\\
    \makeatother

    \noindent
    Actual:\\
    \renewcommand{\foo}{bar}%
    \foo\\
    \storecommand{foo}%
    \renewcommand{\foo}{baz}%
    \foo\\
    \restorecommand{foo}%
    \foo
\end{document}
```

```
Expected:
bar
baz
bar

Actual:
bar
nv@foo=efoobaze oo=fenv@foobaz
```

I hoped that it'd know when I call it to expand the `#1` and then take the entire thing as the command. However it doesn't.

How can I get `storecommand` to work the way I want?

---

To prevent an XY question:

I'm trying to make an environment that reverts to the previous state when it ends. Wiping all commands that have been made.

Comment: almost all definitions are local so automatically restore at the end of an environment

Comment: the argument to `\LetLtxMacro` needs to be a command name token but you are passing `\LetLtxMacro{\\foo}` which is the newline command `\\ ` followed by the text `foo`

Comment: probably you want `\expandafter\LetLtxMacro\csname env@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname` but just restoring via TeX grouping would normally be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storecommand}[1]
    {%
        \expandafter\LetLtxMacro\csname env@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    }
\newcommand{\restorecommand}[1]
    {%
       \expandafter\LetLtxMacro\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname env@#1\endcsname
    }
\makeatother

% Example usage

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \makeatletter
    Expected:\\
    \newcommand{\foo}{bar}%
    \foo\\
    \LetLtxMacro{\env@foo}{\foo}%
    \renewcommand{\foo}{baz}%
    \foo\\
    \LetLtxMacro{\foo}{\env@foo}%
    \foo
    \makeatother

\bigskip

    \noindent
    Actual:\\
    \renewcommand{\foo}{bar}%
    \foo\\
    \storecommand{foo}%
    \renewcommand{\foo}{baz}%
    \foo\\
    \restorecommand{foo}%
    \foo


\bigskip
    \noindent
    Using a group:\\
    \renewcommand{\foo}{bar}%
    \foo\\
    \begin{empty}
    \renewcommand{\foo}{baz}%
    \foo\\
    \end{empty}
    \foo


\end{document}
```

If you do use `\LetLtxMacro` (and it isn't clear it is needed here) you need to pass a csname token to each argument, `\LetLtxMacro{\\foo}{..}` the first argument is the `\\` command followed by the text `foo`, so 4 tokens not 1.