# hyperref - \autoref: small space as separator

Tags: hyperref, autoref

A command like `\autoref{eq:speed}` outputs `Equation~1`. I.e. there is a blank (a protected space, I guess) between Equation and the number. How can this be changed, e.g. into a small space?

Comment: only by changing/patching an internal definition. Imho if you want more sophisticated output a dedicated package like cleveref or zref is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` (or `\nobreakspace`) is used to tie the "`\autoref` name" to its number. If you want a global change of `\autoref` to always use (say) `\space`, you can add

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\let\oldautoref\autoref
\DeclareRobustCommand{\autoref}[1]{{\let\nobreakspace\space\oldautoref{#1}}}
```

to your preamble. This updates `\nobreakspace` to `\space` just for use with `\autoref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764

\begin{document}

Here is an equation:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:eqn}
\end{equation}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve seven Equation~\ref{eq:eqn}.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve seven Equation \ref{eq:eqn}.

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve seven \autoref{eq:eqn}.

% Update \autoref to replace \nobreakspace with \space
\LetLtxMacro\oldautoref\autoref
\DeclareRobustCommand{\autoref}[1]{{\let\nobreakspace\space\oldautoref{#1}}}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve seven \autoref{eq:eqn}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, your example works. However, I have a document class, which uses babel. And when adding `\usepackage{babel}` in your example, it seems `\nobreakspace` cannot be overwritten. Do you understand this?

Comment: @Friedrich: Perhaps you can supply a complete but *minimal* document example that replicates the issue. Start with my code, then post it to [Pastebin](//pastebin.com).

Comment: Your code is already fully fine as minimal example! But as said adding `\usepackage{babel}` to it, `\nobreakspace` is not overwritten.

Comment: Another challenge I have, is that it should apply only to `Equation`, but not the rest as `Figures`, etc.

Comment: If you only want a breakpoint after the text "Equation", you can redefine the name: `\renewcommand\equationautorefname{Equation\hspace{0pt}}`.

Comment: @Friedrich: If it is specifically for equations, then why not define an equation-specific reference, like `\eqautoref{..}`: `\newcommand{\eqautoref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Equation \ref*{#1}}}`?