# Is there a way to switch mathbf and bm commands within the document?

Tags: math-mode, packages, bm

I have written a long document with a lot of equations that contain both `\bm` and `\mathbf`. However, now I would like to switch their behaviour. So whenever I have `\mathbf{X}` in the document, I would like to compile `\bm{X}` behaviour and vice versa. Is there a way to achieve this without manually modifying each occurence?

Edit: Things I have tried:

```
\let\temp\mathbf
\let\mathbf\bm
\let\bm\temp
```

and

```
\newcommand{\tmpbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mathbf}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bm}[1]{\tmpbf{#1}}
```

both of which did not seem to work and freeze the pdflatex compilation.

Comment: Most editors have a global search-and-replace function. It should be easy to perform a `\bm{` -> `\waitbm{`, `\mathbf{` -> `\bm{`, `\waitbm{` -> `\mathbf{` switcheroo. That keeps your commands as expected and drastically decreases the potential for confusion (for other readers and future you).

Comment: The `\let` approach should actually *appear to sort of work* in many normal circumstances, but **does not work properly**, because the commands are actually implemented via protected helper commands internally (see an example of how badly things can go wrong at https://gist.github.com/moewew/c58ef0165e758887dc6dc2c0be88d23a). You'd have to use https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/35864. But really it seems much, much safer, easier and less confusing to let your editor to a bit of search and replace.

Comment: while egreg's answer is a correct answer to the question note that `\bm` and `\mathbf` have quite different syntax and allowed arguments, and swapping them at all only works if your document restricts the uses of `\bm` to cases where `\mathrm` will not error.

Comment: You are right @DavidCarlisle already changed my mind about it but it is interesting that it is possible to some extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\bm` command is very peculiar and you have to look at its precise implementation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
% make \bm the same as \mathbf
\LetLtxMacro\bm\mathbf
% regenerate \mathbf like bm.sty does
\DeclareRobustCommand\mathbf{\bm@general\boldmath\bm@boldtable\mv@bold\bm@command}
\protected@edef\mathbf#1{\mathbf{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{a}+\bm{X}$

\end{document}
```

Of course this might break if `bm.sty` gets changed. It would be ***much*** better to use semantic commands instead of the generic `\mathbf` and `\bm` to begin with.

So I recommend to change all occurrences of `\bm` into `\fooA` and of `\mathbf` into `\fooB` (you will know what better names to use) and then add to your preamble

```
\newcommand{\fooA}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\fooB}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

Comment: I have learnt my lesson for the long run. I will invest time to generate some default notation macros but this saves me a lot of time in the short run. Thanks a million for the quick fix.