# Hyperref error when using letted command in heading

Tags: macros, hyperref

I like to use `\let` to alias a macro to another. For example, I often do something like `\let\brand\textit` and then I can just do `\brand{Aloc Acoc}`.

This seems to work well, but causes problems when `hyperref` is loaded.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\foo\textit

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}

Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

Compilation fails with `! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.` at the `\section`.

Any ideas as to why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, doing `\let\foo\textit` is wrong, see [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/4427).

With an up-to-date LaTeX you should do

```
\NewCommandCopy{\foo}{\textit}
```

or `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\NewCommandCopy` if you're stuck with an outdated version.

But that's not sufficient. Indeed, in `hyperref.sty` you find

```
346 \def\pdfstringdef#1#2{%
347   \begingroup
[...]
403     \let\emph\@firstofone
404     \let\textnormal\@firstofone
405     \let\textrm\@firstofone
406     \let\textsf\@firstofone
407     \let\texttt\@firstofone
408     \let\textbf\@firstofone
409     \let\textmd\@firstofone
410     \let\textit\@firstofone
411     \let\textsc\@firstofone
412     \let\textsl\@firstofone
413     \let\textup\@firstofone
[...]
```

so `\textit` is added to the “bookmark exceptions”, which your `\foo` command isn't.

If you want to alias the command, you need to add it to the exception list.

```
\NewCommandCopy{\foo}{\textit}
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\foo\@firstofone}
\makeatother
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewCommandCopy{\foo}{\textit}
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\foo\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}

Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. Now I feel stupid I didn’t try to locate the problem within `hyperref`’s source code. Could you please also provide some explanation why doing `\let\foo\textit` is _wrong_?

Comment: @bp99 see my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/4427

Answer (score 2):

Package hyperref has some interactions. If I recall correctly, some are even described in the documentation. Find more here.

Why don't you just use /newcommand?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\foo\textit % <<<

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}

Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you can't let /let go, use /renewcommand to redefine your let.

Comment: You are right, I know `\newcommand` works; I should have clarified this in my question. I mainly wanted to find out why `\let` fails.