# Normal \hat along with realhats package?

Tags: packages

The `realhats` package changes the `\hat{}` command, such that LaTeX places a random, funny hat on top of the variable, instead of the normal "^"-shape. I would like to use the package to get funny hats in a few places, but need the normal `\hat{}` to work unchanged.

Can this be easily achieved?

edit: see the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/realhats?lang=en) for a visual example of what the package does.

Comment: Your question isn't easy to understand. Please add a graphical explanation.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better than the package documentation does, but I've now linked that for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\Hat` command when `amsmath` is loaded is defined as an alias to `\hat`. You can reuse this command to produce the standard `\hat` accent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewCommandCopy{\Hat}{\hat}
\usepackage{realhats}

\begin{document}

$\hat{a}+\Hat{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how you can have `\hat` to typeset the standard one and `\realhat` the “real” one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\HAT}{\hat}
\usepackage{realhats}
\NewCommandCopy{\realhat}{\hat}
\RenewCommandCopy{\hat}{\HAT}

\begin{document}

$\realhat{a}+\hat{a}$

\end{document}
```

**Comment**
In my opinion, the `realhats` package should define `\realhat` and offer an option, say `override`, to replace `\hat` with `\realhat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a good step of the way at least. Is there a further hack to flip the two? Just to avoid having to change 100s of equations already typeset with \hat?

Comment: @ChristofferØstfeldt Added.

Comment: What is the difference between this `\RenewCommandCopy` solution and just using `\let\Hat=\hat`?

Comment: I've marked the answer as accepted. Only thing left to add, is that it requires a new-ish version of LaTeX, as the commands used are not available in, e.g., TeX live 2019 (the version installed on Ubuntu 20.04, for example).

Comment: @ChristofferØstfeldt For older LaTeX you can use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package.

Comment: @Gaussler: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro